# How do I revert all local changes in Git managed project to previous state?

Tags: git, revert, git-checkout

I ran `git status` which told me everything was up to date and there were no local changes.

Then I made several consecutive changes and realized I wanted to throw everything away and get back to my original state. Will this command do it for me?

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 4527, accepted):

To revert changes made to your working copy, do this:

```
git checkout .
```

Or equivalently, for git version >= 2.23:

```
git restore .
```

To revert changes made to the index (i.e., that you have added), do this. **Warning this will reset all of your unpushed commits to master!**:

```
git reset
```

To revert a change that you have committed:

```
git revert <commit 1> <commit 2>
```

To remove untracked files (e.g., new files, generated files):

```
git clean -f
```

Or untracked directories (e.g., new or automatically generated directories):

```
git clean -fd
```

Comment: fwiw after such a long time, `git checkout path/to/file` will only revert the local changes to `path/to/file`

Comment: +1 on the answers below also mentioning git clean -f (to remove the untracked changes) and -fd (to also remove untracked directories)

Comment: With the git command "git checkout branchId" it will be listet the modified files but no revert will be done. I must use git reset --hard

Comment: and if you also want to clean your untracked files , read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy

Comment: ➜  API git:(master) ✗ git checkout .
➜  API git:(master) ✗ git reset
➜  API git:(master) ✗ git revert ...
fatal: empty commit set passed
➜  API git:(master) ✗ gst
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 V1/
 css/
 js/


nothing changed

Comment: Be careful: `git reset` reverts your commits to master! (It wasn't clear enough for me that *added* would include *committed*, and I have accidentally lost my changes)

Comment: Can i revert pull changes if the changes were not committed?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763832/smartgit-revert-pull-changes-to-project

Comment: `git checkout .` and `git reset [--hard HEAD]` didn't work, I had to do a `git clean -fd` to revert my changes.

Comment: I added some details on `git clean` as well

Comment: `git reset` doesn't reset your changes, `git reset --hard` does that.

Comment: @Cerin `git reset` acts as `git reset --mixed` ("Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.") which is what I said. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: One remark: do `git checkout .` in the root dir of your project. Or in the subdir that you want to revert.

Comment: `git checkout .` in the root of my project only applied to the files in that dir, I had to do `git checkout *` to revert all sub-directories too.

Comment: _git reset_ unstages, doesn't reset unpushed commits to master

Comment: The warning is totally wrong! First of all, git reset works on the current branch (HEAD) and what it does has nothing to do with the "master" branch. Also, reset has nothing to do with unpushed commits and no you don't automatically lose them just because you used git reset.

Comment: I used git clean -fd following with git fetch & git check <another branch>. It worked!

Comment: You don't always have to use `--hard`. In fact, sometimes that's not right... to do.  You might have more luck with the `--gentle` command.

Comment: Totally agree with @disklosr, the warning about `git reset` is misleading at best and false at worst. It makes the impression that `reset` will somehow revert your current branch to the `master` branch, which is totally wrong. `reset` does not operate on branches, so whatever it does refers to your current branch, even if it's not `master`. Second, it does not change the working tree, therefore you cannot lose data with `reset`. If you have unpushed commits, then the commits will disappear from the local history, but the actual files will not be changed. You can commit the same thing again!

Comment: I would be mean and down-vote this (not that it would matter), but I reverted a change (did NOT push it), and after git reset, git reset --hard, git clean, git checkout, git checkout --force... I finally figured out that maybe, the answer is 'rm -rf .; git clone... .' because the dang thing KEEPS saying I'm one commit AHEAD of the remote, and Dang it, I just reset and wiped out all my local changes so, NO I am not!  Found answer below: git reset --hard origin/develop   Without the origin/branch_name it won't actually fully reset..

Comment: ```git restore .``` only for change in current dir

```git restore :/``` for all changes in the repository

Comment: This answer is completely wrong, at least for me

Comment: If you're used to using an IDE for git like Intellij git interface. Do a checkout on origin/develop(not on develop, but the remote origin/develop or whatever your remote branch name is). It will give you a warning that your local changes will be dropped, select yes and you should see those pesky local changes vanished!

Answer (score 501):

Note: You may also want to run

```
git clean -fd
```

as

```
git reset --hard
```

will *not* remove untracked files, where as git-clean will remove any files from the tracked root directory that are not under git tracking. WARNING - BE CAREFUL WITH THIS! It is helpful to run a dry-run with git-clean first, to see what it will delete.

This is also especially useful when you get the error message

```
~"performing this command will cause an un-tracked file to be overwritten"
```

Which can occur when doing several things, one being updating a working copy when you and your friend have both added a new file of the same name, but he's committed it into source control first, and you don't care about deleting your untracked copy.

In this situation, doing a dry run will also help show you a list of files that would be overwritten.

Comment: The file clean command is "git clean -f". Untracked directories are removed with "git clean -d"

Comment: git clean -fd (force is required for -d)

Comment: -n or --dry-run are the flags for dry-run.

Comment: git clean -ffd if you have another git repository in your git repository. Without double f it would not be removed.

Answer (score 282):

## Re-clone

```
GIT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
cd $GIT/..
rm -rf $GIT
git clone ...
```

- ✅ Deletes local, non-pushed commits
- ✅ Reverts changes you made to tracked files
- ✅ Restores tracked files you deleted
- ✅ Deletes files/dirs listed in `.gitignore` (like build files)
- ✅ Deletes files/dirs that are not tracked and not in `.gitignore`
- You won't forget this approach
- Wastes bandwidth

---

Following are other commands I forget daily.

## Clean and reset

```
git clean --force -d -x
git reset --hard
```

- ❌ Deletes local, non-pushed commits
- ✅ Reverts changes you made to tracked files
- ✅ Restores tracked files you deleted
- ✅ Deletes files/dirs listed in `.gitignore` (like build files)
- ✅ Deletes files/dirs that are not tracked and not in `.gitignore`

## Clean

```
git clean --force -d -x
```

- ❌ Deletes local, non-pushed commits
- ❌ Reverts changes you made to tracked files
- ❌ Restores tracked files you deleted
- ✅ Deletes files/dirs listed in `.gitignore` (like build files)
- ✅ Deletes files/dirs that are not tracked and not in `.gitignore`

## Reset

```
git reset --hard
```

- ❌ Deletes local, non-pushed commits
- ✅ Reverts changes you made to tracked files
- ✅ Restores tracked files you deleted
- ❌ Deletes files/dirs listed in `.gitignore` (like build files)
- ❌ Deletes files/dirs that are not tracked and not in `.gitignore`

---

### Notes

**Test case for confirming all the above (use bash or sh):**

```
mkdir project
cd project
git init
echo '*.built' > .gitignore
echo 'CODE' > a.sourceCode
mkdir b
echo 'CODE' > b/b.sourceCode
cp -r b c
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial checkin'
echo 'NEW FEATURE' >> a.sourceCode
cp a.sourceCode a.built
rm -rf c
echo 'CODE' > 'd.sourceCode'
```

**See also**

- [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) to make new commits that undo prior commits
- [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to go back in time to prior commits (may require running above commands first)
- [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) same as `git reset` above, but you can undo it

Comment: Sorry for stealing from above answers. I use this reference constantly, posting mostly for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the first option (**Re-clone**) actually DOES "delete local, non-pushed commits" :)

Comment: What does the red X and green checkmark mean? Does the red X negate the sentence next to it?

Comment: @styfle ✅  is something it does, ❌ is something it doesn't do

Comment: @FullDecent It's kind of confusing to read. "❌ Does NOT delete local, non-pushed commits". That means it doesn't NOT delete. The double negative means that it does delete?

Comment: This might make more sense in a table and put a ✅ if the command does the thing.

Comment: Thank you, double negatives corrected, because a single negative is MORE negative

Comment: About -x flag in `git clean -f -d -x`:  if the -x option is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example, be useful to remove all build products.- from GIT docs

Comment: i ran `git reset --hard` and it restored my tracked files but did NOT delete untracked files. in fact, when i ran `git status` after, it said `Untracked files: (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)`. which is what i wanted!  why do you say it deletes untracked files, though?

Comment: @calyxofheld it doesn't say it deletes untracked files. ❌ means "it doesn't do", ✅ means it does. In Reset part i see "❌ Deletes files/dirs that are not tracked and not in .gitignore".

Comment: It is worth noting that `git clone ...` does not work as it is, you need to replace `...` with your repository url or use your own custom clone command.

Answer (score 122):

If you want to revert all changes AND be up-to-date with the current remote master (for example you find that the master HEAD has moved forward since you branched off it and your push is being 'rejected') you can use

```
git fetch  # will fetch the latest changes on the remote
git reset --hard origin/master # will set your local branch to match the representation of the remote just pulled down.
```

Comment: It seems important to specify `origin` in `git reset --hard origin/master` (which works) – without it (i.e. `git reset --hard`) nothing seems to be changed.

Comment: I had some local changes and not able to get rid of them by any command I did git reset --hard origin/master and it was able to pull master's changes as well

Comment: @Jake In my Windows 10 CMD, `git reset --hard` without anything else worked for me; perhaps because there were no commits/checkouts/branches, but simply a single modified file?

Answer (score 72):

After reading a bunch of answers and trying them, I've found various edge cases that mean sometimes they don't fully clean the working copy.

Here's my current bash script for doing it, which works all the time.

```
#!/bin/sh
git reset --hard
git clean -f -d
git checkout HEAD
```

Run from working copy root directory.

Comment: Last command gives me `error: pathspec 'HEAD' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: It worked for me when I took the "--" out. 
`git checkout HEAD`

Comment: `git reset --hard` reverts tracked files (staged or not),
`git clean -f -d` removes untracked files,
`git checkout -- HEAD` why do we need this then?

Comment: We dont need the double hyphen. Must be a typo.

Comment: Removed `--` in `git checkout -- HEAD` as this is not a valid command, while `git checkout HEAD` is.

Answer (score 52):

Look into git-reflog.  It will list all the states it remembers (default is 30 days), and you can simply checkout the one you want.  For example:

```
$ git init > /dev/null
$ touch a
$ git add .
$ git commit -m"Add file a" > /dev/null
$ echo 'foo' >> a
$ git commit -a -m"Append foo to a" > /dev/null
$ for i in b c d e; do echo $i >>a; git commit -a -m"Append $i to a" ;done > /dev/null
$ git reset --hard HEAD^^ > /dev/null
$ cat a
foo
b
c
$ git reflog
145c322 HEAD@{0}: HEAD^^: updating HEAD
ae7c2b3 HEAD@{1}: commit: Append e to a
fdf2c5e HEAD@{2}: commit: Append d to a
145c322 HEAD@{3}: commit: Append c to a
363e22a HEAD@{4}: commit: Append b to a
fa26c43 HEAD@{5}: commit: Append foo to a
0a392a5 HEAD@{6}: commit (initial): Add file a
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{2}
HEAD is now at fdf2c5e Append d to a
$ cat a
foo
b
c
d
```

Comment: thanks a ton William, for git reflog. I reset my tree to old version and not sure how to retrive to recent. your git reflog saved me. Thanks once again.

Comment: saved me as well! In my case my adventure with `git rebase -i` had gone wrong (ended up wiping out some commits due to an editing mistake). Thanks to this tip I'm back in a good state!

Comment: What do you mean by 30 days default !?

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy I mean that there is a time limit.  Eventually the garbage collector will delete unreachable references when their age goes over that limit.  The default used to be (and maybe still is) 30 days.  So older references may not be available.

Answer (score 44):

simply execute -

```
git stash
```

it will remove all your local changes. and you can also use it later by executing -

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: use `git stash pop` would automatically remove topmost the stashed change for you

Comment: `git stash drop` to remove the latest stashed state without apply to working copy.

Comment: git stash apply wont add newly created files

Answer (score 38):

DANGER AHEAD: (please read the comments. Executing the command proposed in my answer might delete more than you want)

to completely remove all files including directories I had to run

```
git clean -f -d
```

Comment: To save anyone the pain I just went through: this will delete .gitignore-d files too!

Comment: sorry if I caused you any trouble. Back then I just tried to revert and delete everything in that folder. I don't recall the exact circumstances, but the "-d" was the only thing working for me. I hope I did not cause you too much pain :-)

Comment: no harm done.  I had backups, but this probably warrants a disclaimer ;)

Answer (score 32):

Try this if you are in top project directory:

```
git restore .
```

If not then use:

```
git restore :/
```

If you would like to revert local changes for a subset:

- restore all working tree files with top pathspec magic: `git restore :/`
- restore all files in the current directory: `git restore .`
- file type (e.g. all C source files): `git restore '*.c'`

For details see [git restore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#_examples).

To remove untracked files: `git clean -f`

Comment: Thanks for this. That "magic" is an abomination, though. Why not support a wildcard?

Comment: [SO post on pathspec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27711924/183120) for those wondering. @pdoherty926 pathspec also has wildcards included in its syntax; not sure how well though.

Answer (score 29):

I met a similar problem.
The solution is to use `git log` to look up which version of the local commit is different from the remote. (E.g. the version is `3c74a11530697214cbcc4b7b98bf7a65952a34ec`).

Then use `git reset --hard 3c74a11530697214cbcc4b7b98bf7a65952a34ec` to revert the change.

Answer (score 26):

I searched for a similar issue,

Wanted to throw away local commits:

1. cloned the repository   (git clone)
2. switched to dev branch    (git checkout dev)
3. did few commits           (git commit -m "commit 1")
4. but decided to throw away these local commits to go back to remote (origin/dev)

So did the below:

```
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

Check:

```
git status  

        On branch dev  
        Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.  
        nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

now local commits are lost, back to the initial cloned state, point 1 above.

Comment: thanks, that's the only thing that worked for me - "git reset --hard origin"

Answer (score 18):

The other answers seemed way too complicated, so here is a simple solution that worked for me:

### How to discard all local changes and reset the files to the last commit on my current branch?

```
# Execute on the root of the working tree...

# Discard all changes to tracked files
git checkout .

# Remove all untracked files 
git clean -fd
```

*Note: ignored files will remain unaffected*

Comment: **Far and away the best answer here.**  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Two simple steps

```
git fetch origin
```

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

or if your git uses main instead master use this:

```
git reset --hard origin/main
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this for revert all changes uncommited in local branch

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

But if you see a error like this:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/directory/for/your/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

You can navigate to '.git' folder then delete index.lock file:

```
$ cd /directory/for/your/project/.git/
$ rm index.lock
```

Finaly, run again the command:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding another option here.

I'm referring to the title: Revert **local** changes. 
It can also apply to changes that weren't staged for commit.

In this case you can use:

```
git restore <file>
```

To go back to previous state.

Comment: To restore all file changes in a current local directory you can use:                                              git restore .

Comment: The best answer out here

Comment: Please run git help - you should see it there..(:

Answer (score 6):

You may not necessarily want/need to stash your work/files in your working directory but instead simply get rid of them completely. The command `git clean` will do this for you.

Some common use cases for doing this would be to **remove cruft** that has been generated by merges or external tools or remove other files so that you can run a clean build.

Keep in mind you will want to be very cautious of this command, since its designed to remove files from your local working directory that are NOT TRACKED. if you suddenly change your mind after executing this command, there is no going back to see the content of the files that were removed. An alternative which is safer is to execute

`git stash --all`

which will remove everything but save it all in a stash. This stash can then later be used.

However, if you truly DO want to remove all the files and clean your working directory, you should execute

`git clean -f -d`

This will remove any files and also any sub-directories that don't have any items as a result of the command. A smart thing to do before executing the `git clean -f -d`  command is to run

```
git clean -f -d -n
```

which will show you a preview of what WILL be removed after executing `git clean -f -d`

So here is a summary of your options from most aggressive to least aggressive

---

**Option 1**: Remove all files locally(Most aggressive)

```
git clean -f -d
```

---

**Option 2**: Preview the above impact(Preview most aggressive)

```
git clean -f -d -n
```

---

**Option 3**: Stash all files (Least aggressive)

```
git stash --all
```

Comment: I believe this answer is basically wrong.  `clean -fd` deals with ***new*** files, but doesn't revert modifications.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to delete all the changes, go for `git checkout .`
It's the faster and simpler one.

Comment: This does not remove files or folders added since the commit. For example, I find myself needing to revert most often after renaming a directory which results in a multitude of errors due to "deleting" and "adding" files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

It's a headache, you can try:

```
git stash --all
git stash apply
```

This will discard all local changes from the history and keep the files inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about broader repository reset / revert, but in case if you're interested in reverting individual change - I've added similar answer in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890371/2338477

Answers to questions:

- How to revert individual change with or without change preserving in git history
- How to return back to old version to restart from same state

Answer (score 0):

Using git version "2.37.1"

I reverted all my local changes ( not yet committed ) to previous state ( prior to my local changes ) by using the following command :

`git checkout -p`

Documentation snippet :

`you can use git checkout -p to selectively discard edits from your current working tree`

From `man git-checkout`

> ```
>   -p, --patch
>        Interactively select hunks in the difference between the <tree-ish>
>        (or the index, if unspecified) and the working tree. The chosen
>        hunks are then applied in reverse to the working tree (and if a
>        <tree-ish> was specified, the index).
>
>        **This means that you can use git checkout -p to selectively discard
>        edits from your current working tree.** See the “Interactive Mode”
>        section of git-add(1) to learn how to operate the --patch mode.
>
>        Note that this option uses the no overlay mode by default (see also
>        --overlay), and currently doesn’t support overlay mode.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The multitude of answers here, including the accepted answer, always leaves me questioning which commands I should run.

Many have warnings, and despite visiting this question many times, I can never remember which combination I should, or more importantly should not, run.

So, I am leaving this here for myself when I revisit the topic next week.

```
git restore .
git clean -f
git clean -fd
```

For most scenarios you can simply combine the commands, but as I point out in my explanation some cases require you delete files first, then the directories that hold them.

```
 git restore . && git clean -fd
```

Explanation:

The command `git restore .` performs a checkout on the current branch to the current directory. This will undo any changes made to any files. More specifically, the command will revert all changes in tracked files to their last committed state in the current directory and subdirectories.

The command `git clean -f` removes any newly added (untracked) files since the restore. This command permanently deletes files and cannot be undone.

The command `git clean -fd` removes any newly added directories since the restore. This command permanently deletes directories and their files and cannot be undone.

Note: I am not a `git` expert, just someone who uses git professionally, every day, all day, for many years. I advise you to consult the documenation.

With that said `-fd` *should* take care of `-f` but there are exceptions where it blows up. In my experience, executing all three commands works. It is kind of like calling `Directory.Delete(path, recursive=true)` which should delete all files but sometimes for whatever reason (depending on your OS) you must delete each file first before deleting the directory.

Another Note: Misleading Warning in Accepted Answer And Other Answers: The accepted answer's warning regarding git reset ("Warning this will reset all of your unpushed commits to master!") might be misleading. `git reset` without any arguments defaults to `git reset --mixed HEAD`, which only affects the staging area (index) and not the working tree or commit history. `git reset` does not revert commits or affect the branch history unless combined with a commit reference (like `git reset --hard <commit>`), which indeed can change the commit history in the local repository.

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/1597/