# How to revert working stage to last commit in git?

Tags: git

I have edited some files in working stage (not added them with `git add -A`. no commitment).

Now I would like to revert the changes back to the last commit in my local branch.

What is to do?

I already searched a bit and found:

```
git rebase -i HEAD
```

but then I get:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

So what is the right way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert all local changes in a GIT managed project to previous state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-to-revert-all-local-changes-in-a-git-managed-project-to-previous-state)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw away all your uncommitted changes with:

```
git reset --hard
```

**WARNING:** this really will get rid of all your changes that are staged or just in your working tree and go back to the state of the last commit, so use it with care.

If you might want your local changes back again, and just want to get them out of the way temporarily (e.g. to work on something else) you could just do:

```
git stash
```

... instead

Comment: Will "git checkout -f branch" do the same thing?

Comment: thanks first one worked for me :) - second one I will keep in mind

Comment: @ManjunathManohar: `git checkout .` is slightly different - it will restore everything from the index, so any staged changes would be preserved

Comment: @MarkLongair for that you need to do steps, git reset HEAD . and then a git checkout .

Answer (score 2):

With

```
git stash
```

you can store your currently working state to the stash and will have access to the files later on. After you "stashed", you should automatically be at your last commit.

Answer (score 1):

Now you're into that I'll strongly recommend to give a read to this article, and get it understood forever.
http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want keep those changes then

```
git reset --hard
```

or if you want to keep them

```
git reset --soft
```

if you want to save so you can use them letter on then

```
git stash
```

to apply those latter on

```
git stash --apply stash@{number}
```

Comment: also note the wonderfully easy `git stash pop` to apply the most recent stash.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the command below. It will remove your changes

```
git reset HEAD .
git checkout .
```