# Github: Removing an added file from a PR

Tags: git, github

I accidentally added a built assets file to my PR that would overwrite the one on production if that PR was merged. I want to just remove it from the PR but obviously not make a commit to "delete" the file.

What is the best way of going about that? Should I just click on the 'trash' icon in the GitHub PR UI and then commit that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I upvote your question to motivate you to keep going here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remove+file+PR

Comment: Esp. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39460058/7976758 In short: amend existing commit(s) in the PR and force-push the PR branch.