# Why does `git branch` annotate a branch with `+` and another with `*`?

Tags: git, git-worktree

When I do `git branch`, it returns something like:

```
~/Dev/project/main (main) $ git branch
  bug22
* main
+ feature33
  feature19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using git worktrees.

- `*` Whether or not you're using worktrees, `*` (always) annotates the current branch you've checked out.
- `+` Annotates the branch that's checked out at your **other** worktrees.

like if I tried checking out `feature33` then I would have got the following error:

> fatal: 'feature33' is already checked out at '~/Dev/project/features'

Comment: @torek how do you know it was from 2.23? I don't see it mentioned [here](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/)

Comment: Git is open sore... er, source and stored in a Git repository: just clone it and look for the implementation with the history pickaxe tools. In this case a quick `git log -S "plus sign" -- Documentation/git-branch.txt` turns up the commit hash ID `ab3138146f9ce1d819cefab4515965604de76d9d`, and then `git describe --contains` tells you `v2.23.0-rc0~95^2~1` and [Bob's your uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle). It's a cake of pie, er, easy as cake.

Comment: @torek Thanks. That comment was gold. I learned about `git log -S` & `git describe`. Such a clever way to search for `plus sign`