# How do I revert back to the online branch of a github project?

Tags: git, github

I am pretty new to git, so I wanted to know if there is any command which you could use if you just screw up everything on your local copy of a branch.

Something like:

```
git reclone
```

Comment: Ok, i figured it out. It's just git revert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state?rq=1

Comment: Minor correction - `revert` undoes commits on a branch. If you want to throw away all local commits, you're better of with `reset --hard`.

Comment: (We don't use [solved] title amendments here btw - feel free to add an answer, or let this close as a dup of the specified question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reset your local branch to the remote using `git reset`:

```
$ git reset origin/master --hard
```

Comment: Out of interest, does the `--hard` work at the end? I've always thought it would only work as a switch prior to the mandatory params (I always use `git reset --hard origin/master`).

Comment: @halfer yes it does