# Can someone explain 'git revert ...'

Tags: git, revert

I read the post: [how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state), which is a very good post / answer, so plus 1's all around.

I understand all the commands that are mentioned, except this one:

`git revert ...`

What do the dots mean? - I am sure the answers are on the web, but the search engines seem to ignore punctuation, so I get hundreds of pages of basic `git revert` with no other mentions of "...".

Comment: I'm not sure that `git revert ...` is valid without the ellipis being part of a range of commits to revert.  Are you asking about `git revert ...` literally?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, really : )   ...well, take a look at the post on the link, unless I read it wrongly it is saying that you can use `git revert ...` to "revert a change that you can committed", which I take to mean revert just the last commit...

Comment: @KhorshedAlam ..ummm, no. Did you read the question? I am not asking about "git revert" in general, but specifically what "git revet ..." means - the question you refer to is totally different.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, did you bother to read the answers?  Either the ellipsis is just a placeholder, or it is part of a range of commits.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I did read all of the answers thanks. And no, it was clearly not obvious to me that an ellipses meant a range, else I would not have asked the question. Now its clear from the answers below, thanks to all who answered. A very unfair -1, which means I'll take the good answers, and probably just delete the question later.... no issue for me, bad for the answer-ers of the question.

Comment: I think the close votes and downvotes were because it isn't a real question.  But I removed my downvote.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. But what do you mean "not a real question". Its a vary real question, at least to me. I did not understand what I had read, and pointed to a link where I saw it. Now I do understand because my real question was answered very clearly : )

Comment: Well I think if you type `git revert ...` from the Git bash it will error out.

Comment: Yes, it gives `fatal: empty commit set passed`, but this does not mean the question is bad - I still want to know what is meant by `git revert ...`, and that was my question. I did not ask "What does the valid command `git revert ...` do?"  ... anyway, not wanting to go on about it, but it does annoy me when the dup-police turn up and ruin perfectly good questions just because something sounds vaguely like something else. But thanks to you for seeing common-sense and debating the issue, it helps for future ref if nothing else : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three dots are meant as a placeholder (meaning that you should replace the three dots with an actual argument). They are used as an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) (which is confusing, as `...` also has special meaning as a range operator for Git).

The manual page may be helpful:

```
$ man git-revert

NAME
       git-revert - Revert some existing commits

SYNOPSIS
       git revert [--[no-]edit] [-n] [-m parent-number] [-s] [-S[<keyid>]] <commit>...
```

So `git revert` expects a `<commit>` argument (without the angle brackets). The three dots here indicate that you can also pass more than one `<commit>` argument.

Comment: ah ok, so I am just taking it too literally! ... so its more like doing something like this: `git revert a867b4af 25eee4ca 0766c053`? taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit/4114122#4114122

Answer (score 1):

**Triple Dot** is a `Range Selection Syntax`.

> Specifies all the commits that are reachable by either of two references but not by both of them

You can find good SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6028746) and officalk doc [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Comment: But what does `git revert ...` mean with no commits given as ranges?

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think I am getting it now - I was too literal in my reading of this point, thankls

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen git'll throw an error if you use it like that (`fatal: empty commit set passed`)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think it has no meaning (from what I understand), it was me reading it literally.