# Git : how to drop all changes in unmerged branch

Tags: git

[SOLVED]

I have an unmerged branch in my main repository, not the local one, it has 4 commits by another developer, all the codes were messed up, how can I drop all these 4 commits?

Thanks to @SLaks for your pointer, I just did git pull, then git reverts for those 4 commits, then pushed the changes to my main repository, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I have edited my question, the problem is these 4 commits are not in my local repo, but in the main repo :)

Comment: Then you can pull the branch to your local repo.

Comment: Thank you @SLaks, I know what to do from this point

Comment: @budiantoip don't put the solution in the question, post it as an answer instead.

Comment: Some people don't like that way, I mean asking and then answering by the same person, it's as if intentionally doing it for collecting points, that's why I put the solution in the question

Comment: @budiantoip that is wrong, see https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
git revert <commit>
```

For more look [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes).

Also look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit).

Comment: Hi sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough, the problem is the branch is located in the main repo, not the local one, how can I drop all the changes?

Comment: @budiantoip look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the whole branch both locally and remotely. If you don't want to remove it whole, you might have to revert all 4 commits.

**Local**

git branch -d *local branch*

**Remote**

git push origin --delete *remote_branch*

Answer (score 0):

I think your bet is [git reset HEAD --hard](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) 
Look at this question: [How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716)