# "Untracked working tree files" - How can I just abort ALL my changes?

Tags: git

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1146981/736893), I tried different combinations of the following commands and lastly I tried all of them in this sequence:

```
sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\pathtorepo
> git clean -f

sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\pathtorepo
> git clean -fd

sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\pathtorepo
> git reset

sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\pathtorepo
> git checkout .
```

And I **still** get errors:

```
sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\pathtorepo
> git pull
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        MyProj.DynamicLoading/NetworkMessaging/NetworkMessaging.csproj
        MyProj.DynamicLoading/MyProj.DynamicLoading.Data.Objects/MyProj.DynamicLoading.Data.Objects.csproj
        MyProj.DynamicLoading/MyProj.DynamicLoading.Data/MyProj.DynamicLoading.Data.csproj
        MyProj.DynamicLoading/MyProj.DynamicLoading.sln
        MyProj.DynamicLoading/MyProj.DynamicLoading/MyProj.DynamicLoading.csproj
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting

sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\pathtorepo
>
```

How on earth can I just update the project from the remote branch and completely ignore all my local changes?  I would have just deleted and started over by now, but it's an 8 gig project that took 5 hours to download...

What is the magic incantation? Do I need to find a chicken?

---

```
sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\project
> git reset --hard origin/master
Checking out files: 100% (1179/1179), done.
HEAD is now at ea4b3238 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'

sbees@STRIX-SCOTT D:\project
> git pull
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        Assets/AIBots/Man_Office_01/resources.meta
        Assets/AIBots/Man_Office_01/resources/Man_Office_01.fbm.meta
        Assets/AIBots/Man_Office_01/resources/Man_Office_01.fbm/Man_Office_01_Beard_diffuse.png
        Assets/AIBots/Man_Office_01/resources/Man_Office_01.fbm/Man_Office_01_Beard_diffuse.png.meta
        ... about a thousand more
```

Comment: Try with visual studio closed? Your commands look correct

Comment: It was Unity, after it finally closed I ran the commands again and one file still showed up.  So I deleted it.  Now pull gives me TONS of merge conflicts.  So I did reset again and now I have like 80 of the "working tree file" messages again.  This sucks so much.

Comment: Worth a shot if you're still stuck: `git reset --hard <remote-name>/<branch-name>` with `<branch-name>` checked out (e.g. `git reset --hard origin/master` on `master`). Note this throws out _all_ local changes and replaces completely with what's on the remote, so be sure you've backed up everything you need before you run it.

Comment: added results...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$ git add .
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Now, try `git pull`

Comment: The files are `untracked`. so , can you `add` them first then do `hard reset`? `git add -A`, `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: I did your suggestion of `git add -A` if that's what you mean.  It didn't help.  Literally clicking one single button in the Aurees client fixed it though.

Comment: hm, one more try: `git add .`, `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: It's too late.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So after literally 1 hour of git commands I downloaded [Aurees Git Client](https://aurees.com/), opened it, clicked the big orange "Rollback Changes" button on the main screen and I was then able to pull...

Comment: You probably wanted `git clean -dfx` back at the start, but who knows at this point (and who knows what their clicky button does either :-) )...

Comment: I was having a similar issue as the asker: `git checkout` kept failing due to untracked working tree files, yet I tried all combinations of `git status` to see those files to no avail. Running `git clean -dn` to dry-run a cleaning *did* show those files (`-d` recursed without a path specified), similar to @torek's suggestion. In my case, I didn't need to keep those files, so use `git clean` with caution. :)