# Behavior of "git reset --hard"

Tags: git

I created a few commits in my local master. Before long I realized I should have setup a new branch and placed these commits there. I was easily able to setup a new branch which had all my commits.

What I need to address now is how to remove these commits from my local master branch.

I am thinking I would run "git reset --hard #lastHash" but I am worried about the behavior or running this on the master branch

Since I have not pushed or fetched any updates from orgin/master since I began making my own commits, will the hard reset only affect my local history? My concern is there are commits on origin/master that were created after I had starting making my own local commits

Comment: if it's not a lot of changes, just recreate the repo and make a new branch

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state/1146981#1146981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset --hard <hash>` will only change your local repository, unless you follow it up with a `push`.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git reset --hard <commit hash>`

Where `<commit hash>` is the hash of the commit where you want the `master` branch.  This will [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) the current branch head to `<commit hash>`.

Comment: In this specific situation, you could use `git reset --hard origin/master` and be sure your master will be push-able