# Creating a new branch from upstream

Tags: git, github

I am facing problem in the creating a branch from upstream. Let me explain my issue: 
I forked one repo to work on it.

I made some changes and did 3-4 commit/push into the branch which is master. 
Since those changes don’t  need to merge(pull) into the upstream branch. Then I have to discard those commit and sync with the upstream branch. How can I remove those commit to my branch?

Can I create a new branch which is based on current head of upstream?

Comment: Just to clarify- so your issue is that you forked a repo, made some changes, but now the original repo has some changes that you'd like to pull and merge with your changes on your fork?

Comment: No. I forked a repo and made some changes in my branch. Now I want to remove/delete my changes from my branch and sync with the repo.

Comment: delete your fork and fork again

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said it sounds like you have made some changes to your local master and want to discard them and reset to upstream master.

This seems much the same as this question: [Behavior of "git reset --hard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104074/behavior-of-git-reset-hard) and a similar answer applies.

You can, as mentioned in the comments, delete your fork and fork again (since you have no work you need to save), but this could be a problem if you have other branches in your local repo that you need to keep.  Alternatively you can also reset your local master by running the following command:

`git fetch upstream master
git reset --hard upstream/master`

This will reset your local master to be the same as the upstream master.

Comment: You are right. Actually I had seven commit. I tried 
git reset --hard HEAD~7
But once I did pull it pulled out my last 7 changes also.