# How do I revert to the beginning of my current commit on git?

Tags: git, version-control

I know how to revert to previous commit. But now I did a lot of work since I committed and I want to restart and start from scratch straight from my current commit.

How do I do that?

Comment: If you want to get rid of all of your local changes `git reset --hard HEAD`. WARNING: NO WAY TO RECOVER LOST FILES.

Comment: github != gitlab != bitbucket (doubt your repository has origins on all three). Also, even if you need to force push, the git server software may be irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert all local changes in Git managed project to previous state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-git-managed-project-to-previous-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest commit in the current branch is referenced by `HEAD`, you could just `git reset` to it:

```
$ git reset HEAD --hard
```

Answer (score 3):

`git reset --hard` is the easiest one... but it does get rid of *everything* that's hanging around. You might also consider just saving it in the stash and dump it later on when you are sure you won't need it anymore.

```
git stash push -m "Saving this in case I want to use it later on"
```

That will clean up the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created new files or directories that you need to get rid of, you can also use `git clean -fd` to remove those.

To revert changes in tracked files you can do `git reset --hard` which will remove all new code since your last commit.

Comment: What about changes in tracked files?