# How to cherry-pick only changes to certain files?

Tags: git, github, cherry-pick

If I want to merge into a Git branch the changes made only to some of the files changed in a particular commit which includes changes to multiple files, how can this be achieved?

Suppose the Git commit called `stuff` has changes to files `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` but I want to merge only `stuff`'s changes to files `A` and `B`. It sounds like a job for `git cherry-pick` but `cherry-pick` only knows how to merge entire commits, not a subset of the files.

Comment: If `git gui` is available, then I do it like Cascabel.  If not, then Tyrone Wilson's way is good for fine granular selection of changes.

Answer (score 1003, accepted):

I'd do it with `cherry-pick -n` (`--no-commit`) which lets you inspect (and modify) the result before committing:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commit>

# unstage modifications you don't want to keep, and remove the
# modifications from the work tree as well.
# this does work recursively!
git checkout HEAD <path>

# commit; the message will have been stored for you by cherry-pick
git commit
```

If the vast majority of modifications are things you don't want, instead of checking out individual paths (the middle step), you could reset everything back, then add in what you want:

```
# unstage everything
git reset HEAD

# stage the modifications you do want
git add <path>

# make the work tree match the index
# (do this from the top level of the repo)
git checkout .
```

Comment: In addition to `git checkout .` I would recommend also `git clean -f` to remove any new but unwanted files introduced by the cherry-picked commit.

Comment: Additional note for the latter method: I use `git add -p` which lets you decide interactively which changes you want to add to the index _per file_

Comment: This is not so great in the case that the cherry-picked commit doesn't apply to the current working copy because it's so different, but that *one* file *would* apply cleanly.

Comment: for sourcetree users it's possible to add [custom action to cherry pick without commit](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1026?focusedCommentId=728086&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-728086)

Comment: You can also unstage selectively with `git reset -p HEAD`. It's the equivalent of `add -p` but very few know that it exists.

Comment: @rlat good point, but if any of those files are in new directories, you'll need `git clean -rf` instead.

Comment: Very useful trick. I've put it in a gist in case someone needs it as a quick script https://gist.github.com/PiDayDev/68c39b305ab9d61ed8bb2a1195ee1afc

Comment: This doesn't seem to preserve authorship (at all). In some cases that won't matter, in other cases it will.

Comment: To those of you git beginners getting here while trying to learn: you need to be on the *target branch* when you enter the `git cherry-pick` command, and `<commit>` is the short or long hash of the *source commit* - because I know that a few years ago I had many "where do I need to be to do this?" kind of problems with git.

Also if you want to add a note into the commit message about this file having been cherry-picked, use `git cherry-pick -xn` instead of just `-n`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this tip. All these years of using git and I never knew about the --no-commit option.

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually made me learn something about Git :+1:

Comment: When I do this, `git commit` opens an editor with an empty commit message because `git reset HEAD` deletes `.git/MERGE_MSG`. I ended up using `git commit -C <commit>` in order to preserve the original commit message.

Comment: Instead of `git clean -f`, I use `git clean -fd`.  The `d` means: `Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an
           untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is
           not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to
           remove such a directory.`

Comment: I've successfully used a variant of the above that retains the original commit metadata and works well in case there are files to exclude that would lead to merge conflicts.
`git cherry-pick <commit-id>  # assuming this fails with merge conflicts`
`git reset <files-or-dirs-to-exclude>`
`git cherry-pick --continue`
`git checkout -- <files-or-dirs-to-exclude>`
```

Comment: -n did it for me. When picking a commit from another branch, I have noticed that a regular cherry-pick would pick files from unwanted preceding branch commits into the history, they would later appear as deletions when you modify such a file.

Comment: Works but I had to use the  `-m 1` option of `git cherry-pick`

Answer (score 274):

The other methods didn't work for me since the commit had a lot of changes and conflicts to a lot of other files. What I came up with was simply

```
git show SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt | git apply -
```

It doesn't actually `add` the files or do a commit for you so you may need to follow it up with

```
git add file1.txt file2.txt
git commit -c SHA
```

Or if you want to skip the add you can use the `--cached` argument to `git apply`

```
git show SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt | git apply --cached -
```

You can also do the same thing for entire directories

```
git show SHA -- dir1 dir2 | git apply -
```

Comment: Interesting method, thanks. But doesn't `show SHA -- file | apply` basically do the same as `checkout SHA -- file` as in [Mark Longair's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5717140/321973)?

Comment: Nope, `checkout SHA -- file` will checkout exactly the version at SHA, while `show SHA -- file | apply` will apply only the changes in SHA (just like cherry-pick does). It matters if (a) there are more than one commit changing the given file in the source branch, or (b) there is a commit changing the file in your current target branch.

Comment: Simple, precise, and beautiful; this is the best answer. Exactly what I've been looking for :-)

Comment: Just found another great use for this: selective revert, for when you only want to revert one file (since `git revert` undoes the entire commit). In that case just use `git show -R SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt | git apply -`

Comment: I used git diff instead of git show: 
`git diff SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt | git apply -`

Comment: @RoeiBahumi that has quite a different meaning. `git diff SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt | git apply -` means apply all the differences between the current version of the file and the version at SHA to the current version. In essence it is the same as `git checkout SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt`. See my earlier comment for why that is different to what the `git show` version.

Comment: In case you have to resolve conflicts, use `git apply -3 -` instead of just `git apply -`, then if a conflict occurs, you can use your standard conflict resolution technique, including using `git mergetool`.

Comment: This answers the OP's question in the most direct way. Thanks!

Comment: Really great answer :) Apart from adding `-3`, one caveat is git will complain if you try this with removal of binary files, for reasons I'm not quite clear on. However, that's very easy & quick to do manually.

Comment: note that before committing you have to do a `git add` cherry-picked files. I use --cached to git apply to bypass that, make sure you have added your files to the index.

Comment: @KenIchi that's definitely worth noting - I've added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like this is the most clean approach to the problem. However, git config settings may interfere with this. I had to add the arguments `--src-prefix=a/`, `--dst-prefix=b/` and `--no-color` to `git show` for this to work. Otherwise, `git apply` could not interpret the input (which contained colour escape codes). Probably, this is just because I am using a somewhat weird git configuration. (I am using `diff.noprefix=true` and `color.ui=always`).

Comment: @Alderath Those certainly will cause havok with doing this, and in a few other git based scripts I would expect. I'll add a bit to the answer outlining this, but I'd love to know _why_ you use those settings.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson The `diff.noprefix=true` setting is neat because I often find myself doing `git diff` and then double clicking the name of the file in order to copy it and open it in a text editor. If the name is preceded by a `a/` prefix, I need to remove that part, which is tedious. For the coloring part, I use `cat` as `core.pager` because most often, that seems sufficient for me. But if I ever want to pipe `git diff` to `more`, I want the colouring to be preserved.

Comment: I used this answer just fine a week ago, now it says unrecognized input, can anyone help me ?

Comment: @Chestera I'd look at the output of the part of the command before the `|` symbol and see if it makes sense as a diff.

Answer (score 178):

I usually use the `-p` flag with a git checkout from the other branch which I find easier and more granular than most other methods I have come across.

**In principle:**

```
git checkout <other_branch_name> <files/to/grab in/list/separated/by/spaces> -p
```

**example:**

```
git checkout mybranch config/important.yml app/models/important.rb -p
```

You then get a dialog asking you which changes you want in "blobs" this pretty much works out to every chunk of continuous code change which you can then signal `y` (Yes) `n` (No) etc for each chunk of code.

The `-p` or `patch` option works for a variety of commands in git including `git stash save -p` which allows you to choose what you want to stash from your current work

I sometimes use this technique when I have done a lot of work and would like to separate it out and commit in more topic based commits using `git add -p` and choosing what I want for each commit :)

Comment: I regularly use `git-add -p`, but I didn't know `git-checkout` also has a `-p` flag - does that fix the merging problems [the non-`-p` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20376394/3219739) has?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, I guess it would if you don't choose lines that are going to conflict but there would still be code to untangle if your file has changed too much.

Comment: at least `-p` would allow for a manual edit for such a conflicting section, which `cherry-pick` would probably also yield anyway. I'll test this next time I need it, definitely an interesting approach

Comment: One of the two best answers that don't kill concurrent changes to the branches.

Comment: See this answer for how to select which hunks to apply:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10605465/4816250  The 's' option in particular was very helpful.

Comment: `git reset -p HEAD` also allows the `-p` which can be quit handy when you only want to remove some patches from the index.

Comment: What is interesting here is that you can use glob names for "files to grab" like in '*foo*' and that will be expanded in context of the *other* branch - that way you can easily point to a file that doesn't exist in the current branch/working tree (btw, it doesn't work without -p).

Answer (score 64):

**The situation:**

You are on your branch, let's say `master` and you have your commit on any other branch. You have to pick only one file from that particular commit.

**The approach:**

**Step 1:** Checkout on the required branch.

```
git checkout master
```

**Step 2:** Make sure you have copied the required commit hash.

```
git checkout commit_hash path\to\file
```

**Step 3:** You now have the changes of the required file on your desired branch. You just need to add and commit them.

```
git add path\to\file
git commit -m "Your commit message"
```

Comment: Awesome! Also worked for all changes in a directory with \path\to\directory\ for me

Comment: Overwrites any changes made to the target branch.

Comment: This works if that commit is _exactly_ the file you need (that's what checkout gets you), but does not work if you have any changes (on `master` in your example) to that file (which is what using `cherry-pick` usually solves), as it'll completely replace the file instead of just pick the changes into it.

Comment: If you've just [committed to the wrong branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2941517/584940), this solution by @techdreams is simpler than [using a cherry-pick to pull it into the correct branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941524/584940), at least for me.

Answer (score 53):

Perhaps the advantage of this method over [Jefromi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files/5717615#5717615) is that you don't have to remember which behaviour of [git reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) is the right one :)

```
 # Create a branch to throw away, on which we'll do the cherry-pick:
 git checkout -b to-discard

 # Do the cherry-pick:
 git cherry-pick stuff

 # Switch back to the branch you were previously on:
 git checkout -

 # Update the working tree and the index with the versions of A and B
 # from the to-discard branch:
 git checkout to-discard -- A B

 # Commit those changes:
 git commit -m "Cherry-picked changes to A and B from [stuff]"

 # Delete the temporary branch:
 git branch -D to-discard
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now that inspired me to think, why not skip the `cherry-pick` and directly use `git checkout stuff -- A B`? And with `git commit -C stuff` the commit message would remain the same as well

Comment: @Tobias: That would work only if the files modified on `stuff` have not been modified on your current branch or anywhere between the common ancestor of `HEAD` and `stuff` and the tip of `stuff`. If they have, then `cherry-pick` creates the correct result (essentially the result of a merge), while your method would throw away the changes in the current branch, and keep all of the changes from the common ancestor up to `stuff` - not just the ones in that single commit.

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: I was assuming that your starting point was sufficiently different from the parent of `stuff` that the result of the cherry pick would leave `A` and `B` with different content from their content in the commit `stuff`.  However, if it would just be the same, you're right - you could just do as you say.

Comment: @Jeromi, @Mark: thanks for your feedback, in my case I'm treating branches with entirely disjunct files which led me to my suggestion. But indeed I'd had run into trouble with it sooner or later, so thank you for bringing this up

Comment: I think [my answer in this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32082356/2063546) may be what you're after.

Comment: `git checkout to-discard -- A B` will overwrite the current A and B, or merge with the current A and B?

Answer (score 49):

Cherry pick is to pick changes from a specific "commit". The simplest solution is to pick all changes of certain files is to use

```
 git checkout source_branch <paths>...
```

In example:

```
$ git branch
* master
  twitter_integration
$ git checkout twitter_integration app/models/avatar.rb db/migrate/20090223104419_create_avatars.rb test/unit/models/avatar_test.rb test/functional/models/avatar_test.rb
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   app/models/avatar.rb
#   new file:   db/migrate/20090223104419_create_avatars.rb
#   new file:   test/functional/models/avatar_test.rb
#   new file:   test/unit/models/avatar_test.rb
#
$ git commit -m "'Merge' avatar code from 'twitter_integration' branch"
[master]: created 4d3e37b: "'Merge' avatar code from 'twitter_integration' branch"
4 files changed, 72 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 app/models/avatar.rb
create mode 100644 db/migrate/20090223104419_create_avatars.rb
create mode 100644 test/functional/models/avatar_test.rb
create mode 100644 test/unit/models/avatar_test.rb
```

Sources and full explanation http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/

UPDATE:

With this method, git will not MERGE the file, it will just override any other change done on the destination branch. You will need to merge the changes manually:

> $ git diff HEAD filename

Comment: [I thought so too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files/20376394?noredirect=1#comment6537524_5717140), but this fails horribly if the files have changed on _both_ branches since it discards the changes of your current branch

Comment: You are right, it is a must to clarify that this way git doesn't MERGE, it just override. You can then do "git diff HEAD filename" to see what changed and do the merge manually.

Comment: This worked well for me. A colleague had made a comment on a pull request, that some changes should be split into a separate request in order to separate the issues clearly. Your method worked well for this case.

Comment: You can also use it to grab the specific file(s) from a particular commit

`git checkout e0032947bd37f44044962ae2f7229d339944f83c example.txt`

Answer (score 36):

For the sake of completness, what works best for me is:

```
git show YOURHASH --no-color -- file1.txt file2.txt dir3 dir4 | git apply -3 --index -
```

It does exactly what OP wants. It does conflict resolution when needed, similarly how `merge` does it. It does `git add` but not `git commit` your new changes, so check your `git status`.

Comment: that's beautiful

Comment: Thanks! Can you mention what the `3` is for (`... git apply -3 --index ...`)?

Comment: `-3` signifies to use a "3-way merge fallback". Which in practice means git can insert  familiar conflict markers or it can bypass a change that has been already applied. The default `git apply` behavior is too strict for my taste, it refuses to apply the entire patch on a slightest discrepancy.

Comment: you saved me. thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Sometimes it could be easier to use **checkout** to bring specific files from a commit. In my opinion it gives you more control.

I would do it like this:

```
git checkout <branch|hash> -- path/to/file1 path/to/filen
```

Then unstage the necessary changes to adapt the code and test it before do commit. If everything works as expected, then commit.

Comment: Identical to multiple existing answers.

Answer (score 18):

I would just cherry-pick everything, then do this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Then I would revert the changes I don't want, then make a new commit.

Comment: This is not efficient if the cherry-pick would cause lots of conflicts on files you don't need.

Answer (score 12):

Use `git merge --squash branch_name` this will get all changes from the other branch and will prepare a commit for you. 
Now remove all unneeded changes and leave the one you want. And git will not know that there was a merge.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that merge option. It's a viable alternative if you want to cherry-pick most of an entire branch (but in contrast to cherry-pick it won't work if there is no common ancestor)

Comment: "git will not know that there was a merge"? I thought git knew everything? :\

Answer (score 7):

I found another way which prevents any conflicting merge on cherry-picking which IMO is kind of easy to remember and understand. Since you are actually not cherry-picking a commit, but part of it, you need to split it first and then create a commit which will suit your needs and cherry-pick it.

First create a branch from the commit you want to split and checkout it:

```
$ git checkout COMMIT-TO-SPLIT-SHA -b temp
```

Then revert previous commit:

```
$ git reset HEAD~1
```

Then add the files/changes you want to cherry-pick:

```
$ git add FILE
```

and commit it:

```
$ git commit -m "pick me"
```

note the commit hash, let's call it PICK-SHA and go back to your main branch, master for example forcing the checkout:

```
$ git checkout -f master
```

and cherry-pick the commit:

```
$ git cherry-pick PICK-SHA
```

now you can delete the temp branch:

```
$ git branch -d temp -f
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
git diff <commit>^ <commit> -- <path> | git apply
```

The notation `<commit>^` specifies the (first) parent of `<commit>`. Hence, this diff command picks the changes made to `<path>` in the commit `<commit>`.

Note that this won't commit anything yet (as `git cherry-pick` does). So if you want that, you'll have to do:

```
git add <path>
git commit
```

Comment: this way you can specify any valid range
if the resulting doesn't apply, you can opt-in to 3-way merge with `-3` or `--3way` switch: `... | git apply --3way`

Answer (score 2):

Merge a branch into new one (squash) and remove the files not needed:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b <branch>
git merge --squash <source-branch-with-many-commits>
git reset HEAD <not-needed-file-1>
git checkout -- <not-needed-file-1>
git reset HEAD <not-needed-file-2>
git checkout -- <not-needed-file-2>
git commit
```

Answer (score 2):

Automating a bit more:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filter_commit_to_files() {
    FILES="$1"
    SHA="$2"
    git show "$SHA" -- $FILES | git apply --index -
    git commit -c "$SHA"
}
```

Example usage:

```sh
filter_commit_to_files "file1.txt file2.txt" 07271c5e
```

I define it via copy and paste from here right into my shell. You don't need a [here document](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 0):

## Checkout with Patch Flag

An easy way to accomplish what you are describing is through a checkout --patch.  Modify the four variables I provided at the top.  The script does the following:

1. Clones the branch that contains your commit ( source branch )
2. Checkout the branch you wish to move the file to ( target branch )
3. Checkout the source branch at desired commit revision, supply the patch flag and relative location to the file as a parameter.
4. Add, commit, push

This has always been the easiest method for me.  Step #3 does create an interactive shell though, but you can default option the entire thing if you want to clobber the destination.

```
source_branch=branch_with_file_you_want
destination_branch=file_go_here
rev=757c47d4
relative_file_path=structures/serializers/node.py
message="Patching a file from $source_branch to $destination_branch"

git clone https://github.com/yourepo/app.git -b $source_branch $source_branch
cd $source_branch
git checkout $destination_branch
git checkout $rev --patch $source_branch $relative_file_path
git add $relative_file_path
git commit -m "$message"
git push
```

> If you're remote is GitLab you can use `git push -o merge_request.create` if you need an MR