# How to handle dependencies when using git topic branch workflow?

Tags: git, dependencies, branch

In our project we try to stay close to the "official" git workflow as it is suggested here:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html

We use a `master` and `next` branch, start our topic branches off from `master`, regularly do test integration into `next`, and if a branch is complete, we merge it into `master`.

Now sometimes it happens, that there's some development on `topic-X`. A developer creates `somefile.c` and adds code there that he needs for his topic. After a while another developer works on `topic-Y` and finds out, that he also needs to create `somefile.c` and even would need some parts of that file from `topic-X` - but not the complete file, as it also contains code, which is only related to `topic-X`. He may also have to add other code to that file.

If `topic-X` would be complete and merged into `master`, it would be easy: We could rebase `topic-Y` to `master` to make that code available. But what, if both topics are still incomplete?

Because `topic-X` and `topic-Y` are really unrelated, except for this minor shared code in `somefile.c`, how can we avoid to merge them into each other and still provide both developers with the shared parts from `somefile.c`?

If we create a fresh copy of `somefile.c` in `topic-Y` with only the relevant parts, we found that we get merge conflicts later, when we do test integration in `next`. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

When merging, git will detect whether the changes in the commit have already been applied.

So when you have a commit in `topic-x` that changes `somefile.c` which you also want in `topic-y`, you can cherry-pick that commit in `topic-y`. (Make it easy on yourself and keep this commit limited to only those things you want shared.)

```
git checkout topic-y
git cherry-pick topic-x
```

Later on when you merge `topic-x` and `topic-y`, git will see that the patch has already been applied and skip it gracefully.

This is a better choice than rebasing, since rebasing has nasty side effects if the branch has already been made public to multiple developers.

Comment: Probably the best way. But it requires that there's a clean commit in `topic-X` that only adds the basic stuff in `somefile.c`. In our case the dependencies were not so easy foreseeable, so that there's no such atomic comit.

Comment: @Michael on SO there are tips on how to [cherry-pick only parts of a commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files).

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to consolidate a common base for X and Y in a branch and base both `topic-x` and `topic-y` on that one. Then optimally both branches would not touch `somefile.c` any more, but say `somefile-x.c` and `somefile-y.c` only.

Alternatively a more advanced tool like [topgit](http://repo.or.cz/w/topgit.git) might help you (or not :-))

Comment: That's what we try, whenever possible. But sometimes we find that out much to late, when topic-X has already seen some progress. We only could split `topic-X` into 2 branches - which again is pretty cumbersome.