# Apply all stashed changes within a subfolder

Tags: linux, git, ksh

I had an awful list of old stashes
I have first removed the very old ones

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=7.days refs/stash
```

I have one huge stash left, which contains many stashed changes. Some are to keep some other would damage my production system. I went through the diff

```
git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0}
```

and I know which ones are to keep

I could do

```
git checkout --patch stash@{0} -- myfilename
```

to unstash changes on myfilename and is working fine.
However, I have a large folder with many files with stashed changes inside. I would like to apply all of them but only within that subfolder.

I have tried to approach it using wildcards in ksh but I does not work

```
    git checkout --patch stash@{0} -- myfolder/*
```

results in

```
error pathspec [...] did not match any files known to git
```

The solution does not need to be git based, can be a shell script to wrap git calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
git checkout --patch stash@{0} -- myfolder
```

without the ending `*` ?

Chances are your *shell* expands `myfolder/*` before executing the git command,  and lists the elements which currently exist on disk, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: it does work but then I get a lot of messages like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605405/what-does-each-of-the-y-n-q-a-d-k-j-j-g-e-stand-for-in-context-of-git-p

Comment: how to just apply those changes in the stash without dealing with hunks?

Comment: @Liborio : if you want to bluntly overwrite all local changes, and replace them with what is stored in `stash@{0}`, just remove the `--patch` option