# Can you remove a change when using `git add --patch`?

Tags: git

When using `git add --patch`, you get the following choices:

```
[y,n,q,a,d,K,g,/,e,?]
```

Explanations for each can be found in [What does each of the [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,j,J,g,e,?] stand for in context of git -p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605405/what-does-each-of-the-y-n-q-a-d-k-j-j-g-e-stand-for-in-context-of-git-p).

Is there a way to remove a snippet that it wants you to stage during the interactive git adding? By remove, I mean physically delete it from the file without having to open the file and manually deleting it? That's what I've been doing or stashing it after I go through all the changes.

Comment: Use `e` to manually edit? Or don't stage with `n`, and `git restore .` to restore from the index afterwards?

Comment: using the `.` with the restore command will modify any remaining files not staged for commit. this could cause unwanted changes, tread carefully.  using `git restore <file>` is safer

Answer (score 0):

select `n` so that change isn't staged and then `git restore <file>` after you've completed the patch command to remove those changes from the file.  your `git status` should indicate the file is modified and ready to commit without those *restored* changes.