# Cherry-picking all commit history of a particular file

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Suppose I want to cherry-pick full commit history of a particular file of a repo but the repo has more than one file and the commits are not even i.e 1st commit is to the particular file I wanted to cherry-pick and 2nd and 3rd is to some other and 4th to the particular file and so..

In this case how can my cherry-pick all the commits in one shot of that particular file excluding the commits that are done to other files..

I know,

```
$ git cherry-pick abc^..xyz
```

the command above wont work as it would cherry-pick the other commits which i wanna exclude also..

So my question is, Is there any way to do my requirement in a single command??

Comment: Does any commit updating more than one file ? If it is the case, you will have some conflict.

Comment: ya actually...I will be clear enough sir....from the linux repo i want to cherry-pick all the changes commited to zSwap.c ....so some commits may also update more than one file...in this case is there any possibilities??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the commit history also ?

One option is

```
git show <treeish>:<file>
```

and then just commit the file, Though it effectively "squashes" the commit

You could use this too

[How to cherry pick only changes for only one file, not the whole commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068186/git-how-to-cherry-pick-only-changes-for-only-one-file-not-the-whole-commit)

```
git diff <branch>^..<branch> -- <filename> | git apply
```

Comment: tqsm...The second one worked...I saw diff from commit to commit basis instead of branch :) ...tanx for the answer...