# How to cherry pick uncommited changes in some files into a new branch?

Tags: git, git-commit, cherry-pick

Say I have branch  and branch . In  I have been doing several changes in file1, file2. But, also, I ended up doing refactoring on things that were apparently fixed, say in fileA, fileB.

Now I would like to create a different branch that isolates these changes in `<my_feature>` to have say `<my_updates>` with commits to just fileA, fileB.

Currently I have changes not staged for commit in file1, file2, fileA and fileB.

I have been reading about [`git cherry-pick` and `git apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16068186) but it involves things that are already commited.

Now that none of these changes are commited, I don't know if I should be commiting this and cherry picking or if there is a better way to handle.

To make sure the picture is clear, let's make some visual out of it:

I wanted to do:

```
master ------------------
    \--- my_feature ----/
          file1
          file2
```

But now I have

```
master ------------------
         my_feature ----/
          file1
          file2
          fileA
          fileB
```

and I want to merge this (changes in fileA, fileB) before going ahead with `<my_feature>`:

```
master ------------------
    \--- my_updates ----/
          fileA
          fileB
```

So that `<my_feature>` will just contain the changes in file1, file2.

Comment: Commit `file1` and `file2` on your branch, and then check out `master`. The uncommitted changes will be carried over.

Comment: Use poke's method here as it is the simplest.  Note that using `git stash` also works, but it does so by making commits.  You can make commits yourself and copy things around as needed and then "un-make" the original commits, too.  This does basically the same amount of work inside git as using `git stash` (since it makes commits), it's just a question of what you are personally comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `git stash`, move to a new branch and then `git stash pop`. Then you can do further work or commit the result.

You could also create a patch by directing output of `git diff` into a file (`git diff > changes.patch`) or the clipboard (`git diff | pbcopy` for OS X or `git diff | xclip -selection clipboard` in Ubuntu). Then you can apply that patch with `git apply` to any other branch.

Comment: Many thanks! `git diff fileA fileB > /tmp/changes.patch` and then `git checkout master; git checkout -b my_feature; git patch /tmp/changes.patch` made it.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this is the full set of commands that I used to make it work:

While in the branch `<my_feature>`, store the diff in a patch:

```
git diff fileA fileB > /tmp/changes.patch
```

Stash the changes to reuse them later on:

```
git stash -u
```

Create a new branch from `master` with that patch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b my_updates
git patch /tmp/changes.patch
git add fileA fileB
git commit -m "Updated fileA, fileB because blabla"
git push
```

Go back to the branch `<my_feature>` and recover the stashed changes:

```
git checkout my_feature
git stash pop
```

Get rid of the changes in fileA and fileB, since they are already in place:

```
git checkout fileA fileB
```