# Git checkout on feature branch to previous commit and reflecting changes in other developers code

Tags: git

The project being worked on has several remote developers.

A new feature was being worked on lets say `featureBranch`. Now other developers are on branch `dev_1` and `dev_2` respectively. They took the pull of the `featureBranch` and updated their code and started working on it and pushed their code to the remote over a period of a few days on their respective branches.

Now it was decided that the `featureBranch` code had to be reverted to a previous commit without losing the changes. So the developer working on `featureBranch` did a `checkout` of a previous working commit and created a separate branch lets call it `featureRevert`. Now the developer has asked us to integrate our changes that we worked on the past few days into this `featureRevert`.

Is there any way to do this without having to manually integrate the changes after creating our own branches from `featureRevert` as from what I know taking a pull into `dev_1` or `dev_2` simply from `featureRevert` won't work and won't overwrite the `featureBranch` work.

```
    Day 1:         
    Developer working on featureBranch:     
    git add -A
    git commit -m “Worked on feature day 1”     
    git pull origin featureBranch     
    git push origin featureBranch

    Developer working on dev_1:
    git add -A
    git commit -m “dev_1 changes”     
    git pull origin featureBranch
    git push origin dev_1          

    Developer working on dev_2:
    git add -A
    git commit -m “dev_2 changes”     
    git pull origin featureBranch
    git push origin dev_2               

    Day 2:     
    Same as day 1               
    .
    .
    .
    Day n (Decided to go back to previous commit on featureBranch to lets say day - 10):
         Developer working on featureBranch:     
    git add -A
    git checkout -b featureRevert a9c146a09505837ec03b     
    git push origin featureRevert
```

Now whatever code is not present in between the `featureRevert` and `featureBranch` should be removed from `dev_1` and `dev_2`. Is there a way to do that using git?

Comment: This line is not clear `Now other developers dev_1 are on branch dev_2`. What is `dev_1`?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo updated the question. I made a mistake in the grammar.

Comment: In order to better understand your question, could you add equivalent of git commands you type?

Comment: @Jezz This should be the flow of what happened. What I wanted to ask what should be done so that `dev_1` and `dev_2` branches can get the code from `featureRevert` into `dev_1` or `dev_2` without losing their changes and the code from `featureBranch` being removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use cherry-pick in this situation. Cherry pick your desired commits from `dev_1` and `dev_2` into the `featureRevert` branch.

You can see here [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Can see also [How to cherry pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits)

If you want to cherry pick only changes for only one file, not the whole commit
you can look at

[How to cherry pick only changes for only one file, not the whole commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068186/how-to-cherry-pick-only-changes-for-only-one-file-not-the-whole-commit/16068510)

Comment: But won't that add all the code from that particular commit if i were to cherry pick `dev_1`, including the `featureBranch` changes that were integrated into `dev_1` branch?

Comment: You can pick specific commit to cherry pick.

Comment: I get that, but will that only integrate the files that were modified? Or all the files that were present in that particular commit?

Comment: All the files that were present in that commit.

Comment: So lets say there was a `file-A` in the `featureBranch`. That had been removed when the code was reverted to `featureRevert`. If the developer in branch `dev_1` had the `file-A` and if i were to cherry-pick a commit from `dev_1` into `featureRevert`. That will add the file again right? So that won't actually help me in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068186/how-to-cherry-pick-only-changes-for-only-one-file-not-the-whole-commit/16068510 may work in your situation

Comment: @Rikh Have you got the solution to your problem?

Comment: Well cherry picking would be same as manually re-adding files etc. I want the changes that were removed on the `featureBranch` mentioned above when reverted  to `featureRevert` to be automatically reflected.