# Taking the changes of a specific file from a past commit and putting it in a new branch

Tags: git, commit, git-diff

a while back I changed a file. today I want to add these changes to a few branches. The thing is that the commit of which that file was changed also include other files, which I don't want to be changed in other branches

Is there a way to take the diff of a file from a specific commit and place it in a new branch so I can merge it with other branches?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git checkout master
git checkout pu rtmpdump.c
git commit -m 'rtmpdump.c from pu branch'
```

Instead of branch name, you can also you commit SHA if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
git diff SHA1^..SHA1 -- path/to/file | git apply
```

This doesn't preserve the original author, date, etc.  You could also [use `git cherry-pick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files), but it's a bit more work in this case.