# How to add files to another branch?

Tags: git

For some reason I want to abandon my `branch_A` but I have some files just committed in that `branch_A`. I want to add them to `branch_B`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you use merge, rebase, or cherrypick?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git

Comment: I added so much garbage that I didn't want to add along with those files. Because I used 'git add -A' and I also committed. So I checkout to the old version and create a new branch. I think if merge it will take me much more time. After all I just have 4 files to add.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files)

Comment: @Beat Cherry-picking works with *changes*, not with files. OP does not want to keep the commit information but just the file status, so cherry-picking is not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Switch on the branch B:

```
git checkout branch_B
```

Then, checkout the files you want to keep:

```
git checkout branch_A file1 file2 file3 [...]
```

At last, commit your changes

```
git commit -m "Backport changes from branch A for reasons"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused on how to execute right commands in console which was proposed above, then you have a lazy, easy option:

1) Copy your files out of your project directory
2) Checkout to your branch_B
3) Replace your copied files with checked-out ones, you can even merge them
4) Commit the change

Answer (score 0):

`git reset HEAD^` will move you one commit back. ie. just before you made the commit onto `branch_A`. Now switch to `branch_B` using `git checkout branch_B`. Then `git add` the files you want to commit and then `git commit` them. They will be on `branch_B`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on branch_A: `git checkout branch_A` , use `git log` and record your commit id. Then switch on branch_B :`git checkout branch_B` and use `git cherry-pick your commit id` to move the commit into branch_B.

Comment: This is not the correct solution to the question asked. 'git cherry-pick <commit-id>' moves the entire branch to said commit, not just the selected files.

Answer (score 0):

to selectively add changes from another branch

```
git checkout --patch other_branch file1 file2
```