# Add new changes to any commit

Tags: git

Sometimes when I have done some changes (git diff) I want part of them (only particular files) add to older commit.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files)

Comment: Try `git add -i` (git help add)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the changes you would like to merge in an older commit like this

`git add [path]` or `git add -p`

then create a fixup commit with the hash of the commit you would like to move those changes

an example:

`git commit --fixup [commit hash]`

To merge these 2 commits into 1 you will finally need to do interactive rebase

`git rebase -i origin/[branch name] --autosquash`

Be ware that you have to force push (with caution) after an interactive rebase

`git push -f`

Comment: My version of git hasn't --fixup for commit command. I have created several commits and have run git rebase -i HEAD~<numberOfCommits>. Next I have changed "pick" to "s" for some commits and I have order of these commit.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'add to older commit', I'm assuming you want to amend the previous commit:

```
git add ...          # add as you see fit, maybe with -p
git commit --amend
```

This will squash the added changes into the previous commit. Remember that this modifies history, so if you've pushed that commit to a remote, it may not be a good idea (see [How do I push amended commit to the remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)).

If you want to amend a different commit than the latest one, you'll either need to use `--fixup`, or commit it and then use `rebase --interactive` to squash it into the desired commit. But again, bear in mind that you are rewriting history and may run into not only push problems, but conflicts with subsequent commits.