# Print list of "git cherry-pick"ed commits on local branch which are not yet pushed

Tags: git, commit, git-cherry-pick

After doing:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commit1>
git cherry-pick -n <commit2>
git cherry-pick -n <commit3>
git cherry-pick -n <commit4>
```

I want to print the list of cherry-picked commits. These commits have not been [pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files) yet on the current branch as I am using `-n` option. How to do that?

Please note that I know, SHA1 gets changed after cherry-picking, so the commits should be identified by commit-message IMO.

Comment: As Vampire said in http://stackoverflow.com/a/41717470/1256452 it's not possible in general. However, `git cherry-pick -n` leaves each message in `.git/MERGE_MSG`. Unfortunately, testing shows that it overwrites this file each time, so you can only get the *last* one anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. With the `-n` you tell `cherry-pick` to not create a commit, but to just apply the changes to the worktree. So now you have the changes of 4 commits in your worktree, but you cannot identify from which commits these changes come, except by examining your command history, in bash this would be `history` or to only show the cherry-pick commands `history | grep cherry-pick`.