# How to git merge a file at given commit to current checkout?

Tags: git, git-merge

Here is the difference of `testfile.txt` between commit `319e2d8` and `24bf013(current checkout)`. The `(TO-BE-DELETED)` is expected to be deleted, however it's still in the current checkout `24bf013`. How to `git merge` `testfile.txt` from `319e2d8` to local `24bf013` ?

```
$ git diff 319e2d8:testfile.txt 24bf013:testfile.txt
diff --git a/319e2d8:testfile.txt b/24bf013:testfile.txt/appointments.html
index 66f029ed..86601816 100755
--- a/testfile.txt
+++ b/testfile.txt
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@
 data line 1
 data line 2
 data line 3
-<h1>data line 4</h1>
+<h1>data line 4(TO-BE-DELETED)</h1>
 data line 5
 data line 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files)

Comment: Otherwise you could try `git checkout 319e2d8 -- testfile.txt`, actually that might be simpler.

Comment: @dvaergiller if local checkout has other change than the version at `319e2d8`, then it needs fixing manually.

Comment: Could you expand on that?

Comment: @dvaergiller it worked to merge 319e2d8 to local, and only commit testfile.txt.

Answer (score 0):

It worked to merge `319e2d8` to local, and only commit testfile.txt.