# How can I bring submodule from different branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule on a different branch (**branch-with-submodule**) and currently on a branch without one (**branch-without-submodule**) as such.

```
---(Commit that adds submodule)-A-B-[branch-with-submodule]
 \
  --C-[branch-without-submodule*]
```

What can I do if I want the submodule in the current branch? I guess I can just `cherry-pick` the commit that adds the submodules but what if there are many other modifications in that commit (say, there are multiple submodules) and I only need one particular submodule?

Is there any way to achieve this without manually adding the git submodule again? Perhaps using `checkout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` is your best bet, although this is arguable.

If this is not an option because the commit is dirty, there's always the option to [split it into several different commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits). BTW, this is exactly the reason why you should commit often and push one. Commits are free and is easy to squash them, but splitting them requires an history revision.

`git merge` is also a viable way, but I believe you don't want to go there, because you just want that one .gitmodules addition. So, rebasing is a no go as well.

One final note: if you can't cherry-pick because that commit has the one submodule you need and other files you don't want, you may always [cherry-pick only certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files). Since these are submodules, though, I'm not 100% it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a rebase, in that way you will get the C commit f on top of A,B commits on your branch named branch-without-submodule:

1. git checkout branch-with-submodule
2. git pull for getting last updates
3. git checkout branch-without-submodule
4. git rebase branch-with-submodule