# Different tree branches on Git project

Tags: git

first of all, thank you in advance for your help.

I'm not an expert on git so this is why I'm here...

I'm a developer of a driver in a embedded environment written in C.
I want to work with two different driver structures and use git for svc.

For development (branch **development**) (in this case the driver is developed in "stand alone" mode, with: unit test, build, ecc..):

```
build\
        object files.o
        project.map
        project.srec
        project.lst
config\
        configuration1.h
        configuration2.h
driver\
        src1.c
        src2.c
        header1.h
test\
        other files
        ...
doc\
        documentation.pdf
makefile
```

for production (branch **master**) (in this case the driver is integrated in a project as submodule), and the project needs only the diver sources, headers and documentation:

```
driver\
        src1.c
        src2.c
        header1.h
doc\
        documentation.pdf
```

So, for production we don't want to see all directories or files that are only useful during development phase...

Now my questions:

is it possible to have two branches where the project is structured in that ways ?

is a correct style of work ?

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Claudio

Comment: See..... _in the working tree_? Did you consider using `git sparse-checkout`? So, you want to build for production and there's no point in checking out the whole project, right? Then use `git sparse-checkout` and checkout only what s necessary. No hassle. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

Comment: What do you mean by "for production"? Are those files distributed together with the executable?

Comment: The `build` directory and any other files generated during compilation or development should not stay in the repository. They should be added to `.gitignore`. `documentation.pdf` should also probably be ignored (it depends how it is produced).

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved by method indicated by [Tyrone Wilson] in
[How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files)

That is:

git checkout <other_branch_name> <files/to/grab in/list/separated/by/spaces> -p

In my case, when I modify some files on develop branch and want to apply variation on those files interested on master, it is necessary do:

git checkout master
git checkout develop driver/* -p
git commit -m "..."