# Move commits from linear history to a separate branch

Tags: git

This is not the same as [Split a git branch into two branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355904/split-a-git-branch-into-two-branches) and not [How to move certain commits to another branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369426/how-to-move-certain-commits-to-another-branch-in-git)

I have linear `B---C` history branched from Master:

```
Master ---A
           \
      Foo   B---C
```

I want to move `C` to a separate branch based on `B`:

```
Master ---A
           \
      Foo   B
             \
        Bar   C
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

- [make a branch `Bar` at `C`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491176/6309), and
- [reset `Foo` to `B`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471197/6309).

That is:

```
git checkout -b Bar C
git branch -f Foo B
```