# Where to find branch name that was used to draft a new release in Github

Tags: git, github

When drafting a new release you need to pick a branch you're targeting.
[image: draft new release]

Where can you find the **branch name** you picked for particular release? Can't find it in list of releases.

[image: list of releases]

Comment: A release references a commit. That a particular branch (or many) pointed towards that commit at release creation time is an irrelevant detail. As usual, the question is: why do you want to know?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm trying to create new branch from the branch that was used at release time.

Comment: Just create a branch from the commit `d867a89` then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create the branch from specific commit in different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483983/how-to-create-the-branch-from-specific-commit-in-different-branch)

Comment: Alternatively [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: @AD7six thanks this helped me in what I was trying to do `git branch --contains <commit>`

Answer (score 0):

If the repo is public, you can find the branch under `target_commitish` in the JSON data here:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/releases/tags/<tag>
```

For example, [this page](https://api.github.com/repos/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tags/llvmorg-16.0.0-rc2) shows `"target_commitish": "main"`

If the branch has newer commits, you can click on the release name to open a new page which shows the branch name. For example, this release's target branch is `main`:

[image]

Comment: Not showing for me. Probably because there have been no commits to that branch since release.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that. I've added another suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but private repo