# Git Checkout Particular Branch

Tags: git, ant

I am working on an ant project which I am downloading from git, and need to focus on a particular commit.

It may sound like a basic question, but I was wondering whether it made any difference whether I compiled first or used the `checkout` command first.

I assume I should `checkout` first...?

Thanks :)

Comment: compile what exactly?

Comment: A java project with ant

Comment: and what will you be checking out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should checkout that particular commit first, because otherwise, the classes to be compiled will not be corresponding to that commit (as they might have been updated in subsequent commits).

Once you have made sure that your code is corresponding to that particular commit, you can compile your `ant` project.

To [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167645/how-do-i-create-a-new-git-branch-from-an-old-commit) a new branch corresponding to a specific commit, use

```
git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>
git checkout branchname
```

Or for a single step solution

```
git checkout -b branchname <sha1-of-commit>
```