# Create a new branch containing the two first commits(the second commit version) in master branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I have some commits on my master branch. I want to create another branch which includes just two first commits in masters branch.how can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Branch from a previous commit using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a new git branch from an old commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167645/how-do-i-create-a-new-git-branch-from-an-old-commit)

Comment: @alseether  Thank you for your reminder

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a repository like in the image below
[image]

If you want create the `newbranch` at the `a5d0f81` commit as shown in the image.

```
git checkout -b newbranch a5d0f81
```

should work as show in the picture.

[image]