# Create new branch without local commits

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a few changes in my current branch called "foo".

I want to create a new branch called "bar" from my current branch.

But the new branch should not contain any changes (commited changes in my local system) which are in my current branch.

Example

```
$ git clone ssh://svc@somerepo.git
$ cd somerepo
$ ls
test1 test2 test3
$ cat test1 test2 test3
< no output, all these 3 files are empty >
$ echo "testing" >> test1
$ git commit -am "test"
```

Now I need to create a new branch called new-branch from my current branch, that branch should not contain any change - e.g. changes of "test" commit (mean all the above 3 text files contain nothing) and push to remote.

Is there any possiblity we can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to create a new branch called "bar" from my current branch.
>
> But the new branch should not contain any changes which are in my current branch.

Since you specified that you do not want you *local* commits in foo, but you *want* to include those on the remote branch, you should not create branch `bar` from your local branch `foo`, but from the remote `foo` branch:

```
git checkout -b bar origin/foo
```

This will create branch `bar` on the current state of `foo` in your origin repositoy, i.e. not containing local commits on `foo`.

Comment: I do not want to create branch based on master as well. because there are many changes we made in foo branch. I only don't want my local commits to be part of the new branch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible.

Here's your git tree:

```
----A---*            <---master
```

`Commit A` has 3 empty files committed. And currently you've made a change to file `test1`, but haven't committed yet. So in this scenario you just need to create a new branch using the command

```
git checkout -b "new-branch"
```

This will create:

```
      ---*            <---master
     /
----A                 <--- new-branch
```

This is basic git. You make branches from commit IDs. Its possible to even create a branch/tag/etc from a commit ID too. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167645/how-do-i-create-a-new-git-branch-from-an-old-commit)

Once you've made your new branch you can push it using

```
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

Comment: No, if you see my example in my question, I have comitted the changes. I only don't want local commits which is not being pushed to remote branch, in my new branch.

Comment: @smc Oh, my bad. Missed that

Answer (score 1):

[image]

On Github, type in the new branch name you want and you will be asked like- from which branch to create this new branch