# creating a branch from Git commit ID within Github web UI

Tags: git, github

This deals : [How do I create a new Git branch from an old commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167645/how-do-i-create-a-new-git-branch-from-an-old-commit)  about creating new branch needed from command line on a repository based on commit-id

pretty much,

```
git checkout -b ini_commit_ref_branch cf05eed4fbd76e30615e3876ead9ddb7c5593cd8 # eg commit
git push --set-upstream origin ini_commit_ref_branch
```

But how to achieve same within Github WebUi - as option of creating remote branches we get only on existing branches not from commit hash. Do we have that feature within web-ui ?.

All we see are below icons when we traverse to history of commits against selected branch in repo..

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how you do it.

First navigate to the commit in question, and then click on the `<>` button next to the commit in your history. This will show the web interface for browsing that particular commits snapshot of the repository.

Then, you see a small button with the commit id, just above the contents, like this:

[image]

Then, click the down arrow on this button to show the dropdown. It looks like this one allows you to browse different branches in the repository but you can actually create a new one. Simply type in the name of the new branch in the search field:

[image]

Then click on the "Create branch: ..." link at the bottom of this dropdown, and a new branch should be created.

Comment: This is great!, hovering over that icon didn't displayed any option, but clicking reveled  next steps by itself from UI & of-course after your answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't have hidden this feature better myself. :) Feels like an Easter egg, really.