# Is there a way to move recent commits from master to a separate branch via GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am well aware of solving this issue [using git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628563/3995261). However, I'm trying to assist my fellow community contributor, who has created 2 PRs and made his second PR by committing to `master` (via github.dev) *in their forked repo*, instead of creating a separate branch. What they have now is:

```
master    A - B - C - D - E
```

while what they should've made is:

```
newbranch       C - D - E
               /
master    A - B
```

They were going to create more PRs, but now that commits C, D, E are in master, even if they create a new branch from master, it will contain the commits that may or may not be merged into the main repo (or be squash-merged, for instance).

The problem with doing this via GitHub UI is, github.dev doesn't seem to have a "button" to do `git reset --hard HEAD~3` or alike. Terminal doesn't work there without a Codespace. So, is there a way to help without asking to install git, config creds (and may be some auth stuff), clone, reset, and force push?

PS Following the discussions below, I probably have to add more details that invalidate the "just create branches for PRs [from a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005083/3995261) in master instead".

```
Their forked repo

- A - D - E - F  master (commits D, E, F are used for the 2d PR)
    \
      B - C      translate-264 (used for a PR that I've merged)

Original repo

- A - C'         master (C' = squashed B + C)

What their repo should look like (I'm trying to figure how to achieve this):

      D - E - F  another-feature
    / 
- A - C'         master (commits D, E, F are used for the 2d PR)
    \
      B - C      translate-264 (not used anymore)

so that they can do

      D - E - F  another-feature
    / 
- A - C'         master (commits D, E, F are used for the 2d PR)
        \
          G ...  translate-265
```

Now the only way for the to continue working on a 3d PR which needs work from C' is to make a new branch from `translate-264`. I'm looking for a way to easily return the branches to normal for them, but if it's not possible, branching from `translate-264` will be the most suitable option.

Comment: You are making the false assumption that a branch is anything other than a **pointer to a blob**. You can't "move commits to branches." That is not how branches work. Simply merge `master` into your other branch. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Caleb I know what a branch is and I know how to make the "bad" commits end up in another branch (and I didn't do a false assumption you're describing). What I don't know is whether there's a way to do a hard reset of a branch using GitHub only, which I've explained in my question. The title is composed to explain the initial intention to avoid XY, but other than that, the question is "can the contributor do `git reset --hard HEAD~3` via GitHub (without local git), i.e., remove those commits from `master`?"

Comment: You are asking if "[there is a way] to move recent commits from `master` to a separate branch [...]", which implies that branches are a sort of container that stores commits. That implication is false. The only thing I can think of that you are really asking is, "how do I create a new branch on `master`?", but I feel like you are experienced enough to know how to do that. You seriously need to edit your question, because it is not exactly clear what you're doing. I'll bet the solution can be done on *your* end, using Git. However, there isn't enough information in your question.

Comment: @Caleb Well, since it's still unclear for you, I've copied the illustration from the referenced question. Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: Your contributor doesn't have to do this. You can do it, clone the repo, fix the branches to reference the correct commits, (force) push. If you _must_ do it through the GitHub GUI: delete the branch and recreate it with the desired commit as starting point.

Comment: @knittl sorry, I'm not following you. They have a fork, they made commits to their master branch and made the second PR from master to master. What do you mean by "you can do it"? I don't have access to their forked repo. [Here's the PR](https://github.com/tiddlyWiki/translations/pull/11) if that helps

Comment: @YakovL No, it still isn't clear, because you haven't actually changed your question. You haven't provided any new information, other than posting content from a source which you already shared a link to. You need to actually rephrase your question entirely, because you are asking how to "move commits into a branch." Do you understand how that doesn't make any sense?

Comment: @Caleb well, thanks to conversation with knittl, I've added some more details that may clarify things

Comment: @YakovL even with the new history graphs the answer is still: use a proper `git` client or delete + recreate via the GitHub web UI. I don't see how recreating through the web UI does not solve the problem? Delete master, recreate master from A, sync from upstream, create translate-265 from master. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: @knittl yeah, sounds like a (sadly complicated) solution: change default branch, delete `master`, open specific commit (A), create `master` from there, change default branch back, sync. Feel free to edit your answer and put it there (I'll accept that)

Comment: @YakovL the "sadly complicated solution" is a single command on the CLI: `git push origin origin/master:refs/heads/newbranch +B:master`. My answer already contains the relevant information

Comment: Please note that "squashing" PRs introduces additional complexity and creates all kinds of "interesting" problems that are difficult to understand and cause confusion (especially for beginners)

Comment: @knittl so are you saying that I can push to their forked repo or what? What is `origin` in your command, the original or the forked repo? (feel free to reply in comments to the answer, not the question)

Comment: @YakovL `origin` is the default remote repository of any clone. They can push to their repo if they clone it. You can push to their repo if they give you push permissions (and you add the remote or clone it separately)

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* do it through GitHub's Web UI (but why would you?), you can [delete and create](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository) the branches as required. If necessary, change the default branch first.

1. Create `newbranch` from commit `E` (or from branch `master`; master and E are equivalent). Read [creating a branch from Git commit ID within Github web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004952/creating-a-branch-from-git-commit-id-within-github-web-ui)
2. Delete existing `master` branch
3. Create `master` from commit `B`

But it is simpler to do it via command line. Your contributor does not have to do anything. If you are the maintainer of the repo, you are free to change the branches any way you want (you might need to "unprotect" the master branch first):

```
git fetch # make sure the local repo is up to date
git push origin origin/master:refs/heads/newbranch # create newbranch at master
git push origin -f B:master # make master reference commit B
```

The last two commands can even be combined intio a single one:

```
git push origin origin/master:refs/heads/newbranch +B:master
```

Comment: First, you [can't](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository#deleting-a-branch) just delete the default branch, you have to set a new one first. But more importantly, how to "create `master` from commit `B`" via GitHub UI? As for the command line solution, are you saying that I have an access to _their_ `master` branch?

Comment: @YakovL oh, I misunderstood, I thought you were working in the same repository. In that case, do you really care to what branch they committed in _their fork_? Just set the target of the PR to the desired branch (and `master` seems to be the correct target anyway). The commits are the same, branch names don't matter

Comment: I do care, because they were planning to do more PRs

Comment: @YakovL and why would that be a problem?

Comment: For instance, if they create a new branch while the PR from master is not merged, that new PR (from the new branch) will have commits from master which are supposed to only be in the already existing PR. If there's a way to create a new branch on GitHub via US from a specific commit (in master), that would be another solution to this

Comment: @YakovL They can always create a branch from a specific commit or from another branch, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005083/112968

Comment: Ah, in fact, this is already not good enough since I have merged their first PR and their third PR requires work from the first one, but they haven't synced `master` before putting commits there. So the only option left for them is to continue working in the branch used in the first PR. Or finish work with the second PR, have it merged into the main repo, and then try to sync (if that fails, nuke the fork and create again). I'm sad that they have to deal with this level of complexity :(