# Git - correct commits made to wrong branch

Tags: git

I had a branch other than 'master', say abc, checked out, and mistakenly made changes which I committed locally (no git push). The branch abc was merged into master at origin, prior to my two commits. Additional commits were made to master

Now, I really want the changes of my two commits applied to the branch master starting with HEAD. What commands would I use?

Related question [How to fix committing to the wrong Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941517/how-to-fix-committing-to-the-wrong-git-branch) really misses what I need, as it just throws away the errant commit, but does not apply it to the correct branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix committing to the wrong Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941517/how-to-fix-committing-to-the-wrong-git-branch)

Comment: The second answer in the linked question answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it is not the latest commit in branch abc:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <commit in abc> // 2 times
checkout abc
git revert <commit in abc> // 2 times
```

If they are the latest two commits in abc: after cherry-picking it to master reset your branch abc to the commit before:

```
git checkout abc
git reset HEAD^^
```

Comment: After the cherry-picking, I get:
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 28 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Comment: That's unrelated to cherry-pick. 
In the remote repo 28 commits were made (by others) you didn't pulled up to now. In your local are 3 commits (2 previous and the cherry-pick commit) which are not pushed to remote origin. Fine, that's a standard situation. You had had it already in advance of the cherry-pick - you only didn't knew. 
Before the cherry-pick git status would have told you 2 and 28 different commits.

Comment: as 2 commits are in the wrong branch, you need to do 2 cherry-picks - obvious.

Comment: So, if I want to get everything with origin up to date, then I need a `git push` after the cherry picking is complete and another after the reverting. 

Thanks.

Comment: First you need to `git pull` which will merge your changes with origin/master. If there are merge conflicts you have to resolve them on your copy. Only if everything from origin/master is merged on your side it will be possible to push.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to master and `git cherry-pick` the two commits, `abc` and `abc^` (the latter denoting the commit that precedes `abc`).

To correct your `abc` branch, check it out and annul your local commits using `git reset --hard origin/abc`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to fix this would be to merge `abc` into `master` with fast forward enabled is possible (which will keep a single line of history), then after that's done to reset HARD branch `abc`. As long as you merge into `master` first, nothing from `abc` will be lost since it will be in `master`.