# How to Undo or revert git push in gitlab?

Tags: git

I accidentally push branch instead of master.

So is there any way to revert that push so that I can bring back the master code? I am supposed to execute this command to go another branch from master:

```
git checkout ProductBranch
```

but accidentally I executed this:

```
git push origin ProductBranch
```

Comment: Not clear what was pushed. `origin` refers to main branch in your remote repo, and in most cases it is `master`. What local branch name do you have? And to which branch name did you push it (origin - is not branch name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> "git push origin ProductBranch"
> ```

If `ProductBranch` was previously pushed, you could force pushed its last state with:

```
git log ProductBranch
# make sure the history is the correct one, without your new commits
git push --force origin ProductBranch:ProductBranch
```

If `ProductBranch` was never pushed  before, then you might consider deleting it on the remote side:

```
git push --delete origin ProductBranch
```

Then, simply switch to master and push that:

```
git switch master
git push -u origin master
```

If you had committed to the wrong branch, you can [fix those commits back to master before pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2941517/6309).

Comment: i was in master
and i supposed to hit this "git checkout ProductBranch"
but i accidelnlty git push ProductBranch
.So i donot want to push not ProductBranch

Comment: @BeginnerCoder OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: At first 
i update my work in branch like ProductBranch
and the i checkout into master and git merge ProductBranch 
and git push origin master 
but when i hit git push origin ProductBranch instead of git checkout PorductBranch .So i donot know which step i need to follow of yours

Comment: Was productBranch pushed before at any time? Do you want to see a branch productBranch on the remote side?

Comment: Yes ProductBranch was Pushed  after i completed my given task
then i  execute git checkout master and git merge ProductBranch and again git push origin master.
but mistaleky i executed git push origin ProductBranch in master
so i just need to undo my master

Comment: i am just worried  that my whole project will get messed up so .
i hope you understand my problem

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Then you should follow the push --force option, provided git log origin/productBranch shows you the right commits (the one you originally pushed, before pushing master by error onto that branch).

Comment: So it will undo git push origin PurchaseBranch ?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder If your local PurchaseBranch is correct, force pushing it as shown in the answer will indeed "undo" (overwrite) the push done from master to PurchaseBranch  by mistake.