# Git pull into wrong branch

Tags: git, branch, undo, pull

Myself and one other developer had been merging and pushing our work to a non-master branch called toolwork. That way, we didn't impact the rest of the team. My topic branch was called DPM-93 and my git workflow was this.

```
# do some work
git checkout DPM-93
git commit -m "did some work"

# catch up
git checkout toolwork
git pull origin toolwork

# rebase my topic branch
git checkout DPM-93
git rebase toolwork

# merge and push my changes
git checkout toolwork
git merge --no-ff DPM-93
git push origin toolwork
```

That was mostly working fine until I accidently issued these git commands

```
git checkout toolwork
git pull origin master
```

At that point, a bunch of new stuff showed up in branch toolwork and I'm not sure how to get rid of it short of deleting my workspace and re-cloning from the repo.

Is there any way to back this out to the state before the pull?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

From the [`git reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) (if you just did the pull):

Undo a merge or pull

```
$ git pull                         (1)
Auto-merging nitfol
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in nitfol
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git reset --hard                 (2)
$ git pull . topic/branch          (3)
Updating from 41223... to 13134...
Fast-forward
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD       (4)
```

> 1. Try to update from the upstream resulted in a lot of conflicts; you were not ready to spend a lot of time merging right now, so you decide to do that later.
> 2. "`pull`" has not made merge commit, so "`git reset --hard`" which is a synonym for "`git reset --hard HEAD`" clears the mess from the index file and the working tree.
> 3. Merge a topic branch into the current branch, which resulted in a fast-forward.
> 4. But you decided that the topic branch is not ready for public consumption yet.
>      **"pull" or "merge" always leaves the original tip of the current branch in `ORIG_HEAD`**, so resetting hard to it brings your index file and the working tree back to that state, and resets the tip of the branch to that commit.

See [`HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) for more.

Comment: Would it be okay to use `git rebase -i ORIG_HEAD` to delete the unwanted commits, assuming no one has yet pulled from master?

Comment: @unutbu: I believe the end result of such a rebase would be similar to a `git reset` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC. Sorry for the silly question. Somehow I didn't realize that `git reset --hard` not only alters the working tree and index but also removes the parent pointer in the DAG.

Answer (score 102):

Reset the master branch:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Not sure if this is due to the "correct" answer being 2 years old, but  after trying the other suggestions with no luck, this is what worked for me.

Comment: this solved the problem I had which is that I had pulled into the wrong branch

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

You can use `git log` to find the SHA-1 of the revision you want to be at the head of your `toolwork` branch, then use `git reset --hard <SHA1>` to revert your working copy to that revision.

Back everything up first! And re-read the man page for `git reset` to make sure it's doing what you want.

EDIT: Oh yes, ORIG_HEAD should contain the right SHA-1. But check first.

Comment: Didn't see you answer at first. `git reset` is right (even though a bit dangerous as you rightfully mention). +1

Comment: Prefer this answer, since you're more explicit about which commit you want to revert to. In my case, this was useful since I had a couple of local commits before I accidentally pulled the wrong branch, so I didn't want to do a hard reset to ORIG_HEAD.

Answer (score 7):

I did a similar thing recently, and used a simpler solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628334/2433501).

Assuming that the state of the `toolwork` branch that you want to revert to **has been pushed** to `origin`, you can simply do

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/toolwork
```

In my case, the value of `ORIG_HEAD` had been overwritten by another merge on a different branch, and doing this I didn't have to worry about searching for the correct commit in the log.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is simply

> `git reset --hard`

I did this from the local repository with the unfortunate merge/pull:

```
Laptop@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx /d/Google Drive/xxxxxxx/Github/xxxxx (staging_ec2|MERGING)
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 2d5a511 [last commit comment]

Laptop@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx /d/Google Drive/xxxxxxx/Github/xxxxx (staging_ec2)
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

```
git log

git reset --hard <hash>,
```

The hash is something like `0928817nsbn78867hs3g5666`

Example: if you `git log`, you will get:

```
commit 0928817nsbn78867hs3g5666 (HEAD -> yourrepo, origin/yourrepo)
```

Step 2:

`git reset --hard 0928817nsbn78867hs3g5666`

Answer (score 0):

You can abort that merge using below command

```
git merge --abort
```

It will simply undo the accidental pull...