# Is 'git reset --hard Head~1' enough to undo a git pull?

Tags: git

I am a git newbie, I am trying to understand to undo changes in git. Say I have two branches

1: master
2: work

I am working in work branch and I want to pull the latest changes from my teammates in work branch, so I am supposed to give the command

```
git pull origin work
```

But instead, I gave the command

```
 git pull origin master
```

It fetches a bunch of commits from master branch.Now, I want to undo the last pull(assuming no local uncommited changes), will this command be sufficient

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Will the above command accomplish undoing git pull? Is there any scenario where it might not work?

Edit

After reading the answers, Do HEAD~1 and ORIG-HEAD refer to the same commit after a pull/merge?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998881/git-pull-into-wrong-branch

Comment: HEAD~1 only undoes 1 commit, okay for merges. However the pull may have added multiple commits (fast forwards). You should `git log` to see what was added. (Best is to `git tag X` before pulling). You can `git branch -f master <last_good_commit>` if you don't want to count the pulled commits.

Comment: It is better use `git reflog` than being looking for the git log.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `git reset` does not take `--head` option, I think you mean `--hard`.  Second, no, it's not enough as `git reset --head HEAD~1` will take your repository to the state of the previous commit. If `git pull` resulted in many new commits, it would not be enough. You need to do:

```
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

It works because before doing merge, rebase and other potentially dangerous operations `Git` sets a special reference called `ORIG_HEAD` equal to the `SHA1` of current HEAD before this operation. Next time before doing `git pull` note `SHA1` of the current `HEAD` and after `git pull` see yourself that `ORIG_HEAD` points the previous `HEAD`:

```
$  cat .git/ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: I have tried git pull twice one with fast forward and one with recursive. In both of the cases, git pull added one commit in git reflog, and git reset --hard HEAD~1, undid the git pull. So in what scenario will git pull result into more than one commit(in git reflog?)

Comment: @Dude: did `git pull` add only commit or did it add many commits?

Comment: More than one commit. I can post the logs also if you want?

Comment: @Dude: no, it's not necessary. In this command : `git reset --hard HEAD~1` a number after `~` means how many commits back you would like to go. You can read about it in `man gitrevisions`. If you pulled only one commit, it would work like a charm because it would bring you exactly one commit back - it's where you were before doing `git pull`. However, if you pulled multiple commits, it would bring you back to one of the commits you *pulled* and not the commit you were on before you did a `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `git gui` and `gitk` to see the history and do the resets.

But if you want to use the terminal:

To see where the HEAD was before the pull

```
git reflog
```

You should see the SHA1 of the previous position of the HEAD.

Then ( As suggested by Kenney ):

```
git reset --hard <previousSHA1>
```

or:

```
git branch -f master <previousSHA1>
```