# git pull analogous to / opposite of git push -f?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-fetch

Sometimes, esp. when I'm the only one working on a remote repository, I like rewriting the history with `git rebase -i` and `git push origin master -f`.

How do I do a forced `git pull origin master` without a merge? I tried it with the `-f` option, but that didn't work. I just want to rewrite the history of my local git repo to match that of the remote (origin).

Comment: @Matt Age is not (always) relevant for deciding on duplicates, and as the linked question has more upvotes, and more detailed answers it is a good candidate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't know, i think closing something as a duplicate retrospectively isn't logical.

Comment: @Matt This is the guidance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks i'll have a deeper read of that, but just glancing at the MOD answer i can see i was mistaken and this is the correct action to mark it as a duplicate and i stand corrected.... and marked as dupe

Comment: Also could possibly be seen as duplicate of [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628088/1148030)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: After `git fetch`, of course.

Comment: Note, this only works for a clean branch. Any changes or new commits in the local working copy will be lost. I've added an answer using `rebase`.

Answer (score 19):

With respect it is a few years old, the [answer by MattDiPasquale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898318/164998) will destroy any local changes or commits.

If you have local changes or commits, but need to rewrite history, run:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: If all you need to preserve is your current unstaged work (not local commits) just type `git stash && git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master && git stash pop`

Comment: Will that work if the old origin/master and your local origin master have no common root (e.g. origin history was rewritten changing all commits' SHA)?