# Changing commit message and user ID info in already checked in code

Tags: git

I am admin for my bitbucket project .

We have some checkins done on the brach  .

Say `checkin_1, checkin_2,checkin_3,checkin_4,checkin_5`

I want to edit commit messages in checkin_2,checkin_3,checkin_4 , including user who checked in . Basically some personal email address was wrongly put by a person and commit message is garbled .

I want to have correct commit messages for future reference & correct the email address used there as well  .

How can i do so . Given that i am an admin , i think its possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone your BitBucket repo, fix it locally, and force a push (since you will have changed the history).
That can be an issue if others have already cloned the repo: you need to communicate they need to reset their own local copy: see "[`git pull` after forced update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813888/6309)".

You can do an interactive rebase, and, as described in "[Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/6309)"

> change the text from pick to edit next to the hash of the one you want to modify. Then when git prompts you to change the commit, use this:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

In your case, if `change1` if the oldest commit, and `change5` the most recent:

```
git rebase -i change1~
```