# Why do git reset & push use slashes vs spaces between remote and branchname?

Tags: git, github, version-control

A hard [git reset is often used after a force push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813816/git-pull-after-forced-update) or forced update to copy all remote changes of a branch. For example after a rebase and a force push with

```
git push --force origin my_branch
```

your team member can use

```
git reset --hard origin/my_branch
```

to get the updated branch. The question is why do you have to specify a slash `/` for `git reset`, but not for `git push` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more of a long comment rather then a proper answer.

I suppose generic answer to this would be something like:

> "it has been programmed that way"

On a more serious note, perhaps it has something to do with the resources and their location. What I mean by resources here is `local` or `remote`.

Let's look at the two commands you've mentioned in your original post.

`git push -f <remote> <branch>`

So what does push actually do? Simplistically it takes whatever you've got on your local repository and pushes it upstream to the remote repository. How would we do that? From design perspective, if you think about it, it makes a perfect sense to pass two parameters in this case a `remote` a place where you will send your changes and `branch` from your local system which you will be preserving long-term.

Next, let's look at

`git reset --hard <remote>/<branch>`

This instruction basically resets your *working directory* to whichever *index* you specify. Also, note this is all done from your `local file system` and this is the difference between the two commands you've brought up in your *OP*.

Comment: This is, in fact, the right answer: the last argument to `git push` is not a branch name, but rather a *refspec*, consisting in this case of a *pair* of branch names: some sort of commit specifier in your repository, then a colon, then the name in *their* (origin's) repository that you want *them* to change. The last argument to `git reset`, on the other hand, is simply any suitable commit specifier. A branch name (regular local branch like `foo`, or remote-tracking branch like `origin/foo`) works fine as a commit-specifier, but so does a hash like `a1234567`. (continued)

Comment: On the other hand, the final part of the *refspec* argument to `git push` *must* be a name, never a raw commit hash. Plus, it's *their* name, rather than yours! Hence it's never `origin/foo`. The funny thing about `git push` refspecs is that you can omit *their* name (and the colon) if you use a name on your side. The precise details vary but usually that means "same name on both sides". That is, `foo:foo` can be shortened to just `foo`.

Comment: @torek would you mind making appropriate modifications to my answer above to reflect on what you've just said in the comment section. I totally agree with it and its technically better defined. Or if you don't mind, I could integrate appropriate changes myself with your approval

Comment: I'll leave it to you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `git push` command first takes a `remote` parameter, where you specify the repo you're pushing to followed by the local branch ref to update the corresponding remote branch with.

`git reset`, however, takes a single *path* parameter where you are specifying the branch of the remote repo (via a path) to reset the local copy to.

To answer your question directly, the reason you need a slash for `git reset` is because it takes one parameter which is a path rather than `git push` which takes two separate parameters: a remote and a branch.

You may wish to refer to [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) and [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) official documentation for Git.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why the / ?

In `git push <remote> <branch>` you are giving two parameters: the remote name and the branch name. Hence no reason to add a `/`. The `remote` is an essential part here; after all, `push` will communicate with it.

In `git reset ... origin/my_branch` you are giving *one* parameter: the name of a branch. In this context, `origin/my_branch` *is* the name of the branch, fully specified. You could also give the name of a local branch here (in which case you would leave off the `.../` part. So if there were a space in between (instead of using the fully qualified branch name), it would become quite confusing and error prone. `reset` does not care about or even know about remotes.

#### Careful

> git reset --hard origin/my_branch

This needs a `git checkout my_branch` first or you will reset whatever other branch you are currently on. You might want to edit your question so people who stumble across it don't get the wrong impression.

#### Keep their changes

More importantly, there is no need to do a hard reset (i.e. to throw away all locally committed changes on the branch) after a rebase was force-pushed. Your colleagues can simply do the *same* rebase operation on their end, and then everything is fine again (well, not in pathologigal cases with lots and lots of conflicts, of course). The "rerere cache" can help here (see `git help rerere`).

So, if *you* did:

```
git checkout my_branch
git rebase abc12345
git push --force
```

Then they can do:

```
git fetch   # in case they do not have abc12345 yet
git checkout my_branch
git rebase abc12345
git pull
```

The rebase operation is repeatable, so this should work well, usually. This will let the other developers keep all their local changes and get yours on top (remember that the `pull` is basically a `merge`).

Comment: The bad thing about deleting, then re-creating, the branch (`git branch -D my_branch` followed by `git checkout my_branch`) is that this discards your reflog for `my_branch`. Well, that, and, accidentally using the wrong name (for a private branch that has no upstream) could be even worse. :-)

Comment: I like the `git branch -f` method too, except for one other problem: if you're actually *on* that branch at the time, it moves the label without altering your index and work-tree. This leaves you with a whole lot of "changes to be committed" if you had a clean index and work-tree before. (Which you can then fix with `git reset --hard`, but you need to know to check, and to understand why that just happened.) It does show that there is no need to leave the current branch, if the upstream rebase you need to deal with affected some *other* branch.

Comment: Gah, you're completely right. I've removed that part of my answer, hard to get right without stepping into difficulties; and it is not the important part anyways. ;)