# How do I sync a GitHub forked repository with upstream after rewrite of master?

Tags: git, github

I have some forked repository with my feature branches. I kept it up-to-date with the upstream using [fetch/merge](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).
At some point, upstream owner edited one commit (C2) and rewrote the whole history from that point forward (C2'-C3').

```
----C1---C2'--...---C3'--C5---...---C6(upstream/master)
     \
      ---C2---...---C3(origin/master)
                     \
                      ---C4(origin/feature-branch)
```

How can I get my fork synced now? I'd like to somehow rewrite C2-C3 with C2'-C3', rebase C4 on top of C3' and then sync my fork up to C6. I'd like to avoid just merging C6 into C3.

**SOLVED:**

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git reset --hard upstream/master --
$ git push origin +master
$ git checkout feature-branch
$ git reset --hard master --
$ git cherry-pick C4
$ git push origin +feature-branch
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull after forced update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813816/git-pull-after-forced-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's only a few commits, you can always use `git cherry-pick` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

One way to do this is to clone your main branch, reset the main branch to upstream/master, then cherry pick the commits you want from the cloned branch.