# Reset local repo to be exactly the same as remote repo

Tags: git

How do I reset my local git repo to be exactly the same as the remote repo?

I've tried:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

But now `git status` says I have diverging commits. I basically want to just wipe anything I've got locally and get the exact remote repo on my local machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset my local repository to be just like the remote repository HEAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/how-to-reset-my-local-repository-to-be-just-like-the-remote-repository-head)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD^` will only reset your working copy to the previous (parent) commit. Instead, you want to run

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Assuming remote is `origin` and the branch you want to reset to is `master`

Comment: in my case I also need to run "git pull" to point my local master correctly. otherwhise my local would stay in detached mode

Comment: If you want to remove local untracked files, you can run `git clean` first. Run `git clean -n` to see what would happen (i.e. which files would be removed), and `git clean -f` to actually remove them.

Comment: This will only reset the given branch. Not the full repo as was asked by OP. Just to be aware.

Comment: Is it possible to revert this command?

Comment: @IvanaMurray yes with the `git reflog` command you can see the history of the HEAD, and pass it to `git reset --hard` as well

Answer (score 17):

You could delete the current branch, and create the branch again at the remote/branchname commit

```
git branch -D branchname
git checkout remote/branchname
git branch branchname
```

Comment: Why the down votes?  What's wrong with this strategy?