# git reset --hard fails if branch name contains slashes

Tags: git

According to [How to reset my local repository to be just like the remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/how-to-reset-my-local-repository-to-be-just-like-the-remote-repository-head) you can set your local branch to match the remote branch by

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

which works fine for branches that don't have slashes in their names.

For my remote branch 'topic/something' with the command

```
git reset --hard origin/topic/something
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/topic/something': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

What is the correct syntax for branch names containing slashes? Thanks.

Comment: … is it even possible to have a branch name containing slashes? Are you sure you don’t just want `topic/something`?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` show?  What about `git rev-parse origin/topic/something`? And, @minitech: sure, slashes in branch names are fine.

Answer (score 3):

I found what was missing. I only did

```
git fetch origin topic/something
```

before I tried the `git reset --hard` command.
But I needed to do

```
git fetch --all
```

as well. Then

```
git reset --hard origin/topic/something
```

worked.
Thanks for your help.