# Reset branch completely to repository state?

Tags: git

On a shared feature branch, I've checked out the branch and inadvertently rebased it to master, causing a slew of problems as it's a shared branch and I should have done `git merge`.

How can I revert this entire branch to be exactly the state of the branch in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done it only locally you can switch to branch master, delete your local feature branch and checkout the remote branch gain:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d featurebranch
git fetch
git checkout -b featurebranch origin/featurebranch
```