# Git: Reset forked repo to current copy of upstream repo

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I made some unwanted changes to my forked copy of an upstream repo, and the upstream repo has also changed in that time. So what I want to do is to basically fork a fresh copy of the upstream repo without keeping any of my changes.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out at all how to do this. I have tried three methods:

1. Following the instructions at [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-a-github-forked-repository) except for the rebase (I don't want my own commits to be replayed). This tells me I am up to date and no changes are made, but my forked repo is still not the same as the current upstream repo.
2. Following the instructions at [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head) . This works with the files and changes them, however it also assumes that I am now editing the upstream repo instead. My forked copy does not reset.
3. Following the instructions at http://www.hpique.com/2013/09/updating-a-fork-directly-from-github/ however I do not get the option of 'switching the base' when I do that.

I'm quite new to GitHub, unfortunately, which makes everything all the more confusing. I suppose as a last resort I could delete my forked repo and start all over again but I would rather not do that if possible.

Edit: Fixed with VonC's help. Needed to clone the upstream repo to a fresh folder as my local copy instead of the existing folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to discard your changes, and reset everything to the upstream (original) repo state, you could:

- git clone the original repo (not your fork)
- rename the remote origin to upstream

  ```
    git remote rename origin upstream
  ```
- add origin with the url of your fork:

  ```
    git remote add origin https://github.com/<you>/<yourFork>
  ```
- push/reset all the branches to your fork:

  ```
    git push origin --force --all
  ```

(see [the discussion for an illustration of those commands](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92246/discussion-between-vonc-and-melange))

Comment: Thanks @VonC but for some reason it doesn't seem to solve the problem... it says "everything up to date" but when I check my repo on github.com none of the changes went through, it still says "This branch is 7 commits ahead of <upstream>". I think I did everything as per instructions except for the fact that I already had a remote upstream so I had to remove it. I will attach a screenshot of my command line logs so you can see if I'm doing anything wrong, if you don't mind.

Comment: @melange right: that is because the branch configuration still says: `branch.xxx.remote upstream`. Replace `upstream` by `origin` in your `.git/config` for every `branch.xxx.remote` line, and try the `git push --force --all` again.

Comment: VonC, you mean edit the upstream URL in the config file in my .git directory, right?

Comment: @melange no: that was done by the git remote commands above. I mean changing the word `upstream` by `origin` in the lines of the `.git/config` file with `branch.xxx.remote` (like `branch.master.remote upstream` changed into `branch.master.remote origin`)

Comment: Do you mean lines like this in the .git/config? `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*` I have replaced that and rerun the git push but it seems to produce the same result. I'll attach another screenshot... Sorry about that, and thanks for the patience!

Comment: @melange no the lines which include `branch.<abranchname>.remote`

Comment: There is no such line in my .git/config file though. :( I have pasted the entire config file in my opening post.

Comment: @melange I just saw your config file, And I don't understand why upstream and origin seem to have the same url. The git remote commands I mentioned should have set them to two different url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92246/discussion-between-vonc-and-melange).

Comment: @melange You cloned the repo and then ran the command without cd-ing to the repo folder. The rest of the commands should be run from the project root

Comment: @VonC I think the local folder he is cloning to also has a parent .git repo

Comment: @melange can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92246/discussion-between-vonc-and-melange ?

Comment: @HarishVed can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92246/discussion-between-vonc-and-melange?