# git: reset to remote branch

Tags: git, reset, git-checkout

After cloning a repository I cannot reset that repository's state to a remote branch.

```
$ git clone <repo>
$ git reset --hard <upstream branch>
fatal: ambiguous argument '<upstream branch>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]
```

What works fine is either prefixing with `origin`

```
$ git reset --hard origin/<upstream branch>
```

or do a checkout before

```
$ git checkout <upstream branch>
$ git reset --hard <upstream branch>
```

Questions:

1. What extra information or state change does the checkout command provide to the local git repository so that it eventually can reset its state?
2. Is there a command (like checkout) I can run before the reset command that is not branch specific?

Comment: Just to make sure: did you write a real branch's name and not `'<upstream branch>'` verbatim?

Comment: Also note that you can't "reset the state of a repository" to a certain branch: the repository contans all the branches of the repository which was cloned. `git reset` can be used to reset the state of *a branch* (and also of the index and the work tree, if asked, or only the index and the work tree or only the index) but not the repository as a whole. Consider reading [this](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html).

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question. Unless, you are asking about git internals, then that would be a different question, and in that case you should re-word your post.

Comment: The following question has a lot of good info in answers, for those who arrive here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Git cannot find a reference to a branch named `upstream_branch` in your fresh local repo, because it doesn't exist. But the reference for `origin/upstream_branch` does exist. Run `git branch --all` and you'll see the full list of branches in your repository, both local and remote.

In the second working scenario, when you run `git checkout upstream_branch` you created a local branch named `upstream_branch` set up to track remote branch `origin/upstream_branch`. That's why the subsequent `git reset` command works.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *"reset that repository's state to a remote branch"* ?

If you want a local branch equal to the remote branch just use **git checkout*:

```
git checkout -b local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

If you have a dirty workspace, and you want to get rid of any added/modified file you can type:

```
git clean -f
git checkout -f -b local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

Comment: The example might indeed be too simple. Imagine a workspace made dirty before the reset command.

Comment: Then, check my new answer.