# Undo changes in git not staged (master branch)

Tags: git, github

I've got a master branch and someone did a few changes in it which I don't want. Is it possible to undo the changes without committing?

Current status:

```
git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   bazinga.php
        modified:   bazinga2.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So basically revert to the old bazinga/bazinga2 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One answer hides in the git status information

> (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

Try to use the command below.

```
git checkout bazinga.php
git checkout bazinga2.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting your branch to exactly match the remote branch can be done

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Or

```
git checkout .
```

Reference: [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)