# How to avoid merge conflicts from pull?

Tags: git

I keep the repositories of several open source projects locally for reference. I update them infrequently and the result is that I end up with merge conflicts. When it comes to the Linux kernel this can be hundreds of files.

How can I tell git to pull from upstream and accept all changes blindly?

Comment: I think the question this has been marked duplicate of is not accurate. This question is perhaps the real duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628088/1148030 and has the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git pull --strategy theirs` should have you covered :)

Comment: On my git version 2.25.1 this does not work. It gives `Could not find merge strategy 'theirs'` Maybe it existed in an older version of git?

Comment: I think now it would be `git pull --strategy recursive --strategy-option=theirs` aka `git pull -s recursive -Xtheirs`