# Git clone - create a bare clone but with remote tracking branches (for a worktree 'main' repo)

Tags: git, git-worktree

For use with worktrees, I'm trying to make a bare clone but where remote branches *are* mapped to remote tracking branches.

I'm trying to set up a generic worktree workflow. My repo is really really big, so cloning it is expensive. And even using hard links, as repos get `gc`ed, they tend to diverge over time and use up extra space, and a fetch in one repo is does not help another, so working in worktrees seems the obvious thing to do. (You'll have to trust me on this.)

Worktrees require a 'main' repo that actually holds the objects. Obviously, that clone must not be deleted, so I'd like to put it somewhere like `/var/cache/git/reponame.wt.git`. (I'm making a generic solution for me and my colleagues, so I've got to make it fairly foolproof.)

I *could* make it a regular clone, but then it has to have a branch checked out and then that branch cannot be checked out by any other worktree, so I'd have to make a dummy branch (e.g. `wt_dummy`) that could confuse people. What I'd really rather do is make the main repo a `bare` repo.

The trouble is that `git clone --bare` does not create remote tracking branches. So to make a "bare repo but with remote tracking branches", I've started on this path

```
git clone --bare <remote> repo.tmp
mv repo.tmp.git reponame.wt.git
cd reponame.wt.git
git config core.bare true
git config --remove-section branch.master
... and I'm not quite there yet ...
```

But a) it seems too long and complicated, and b) the git repository still thinks it has `master` checked out.

Is there a better way to make this "bare clone with remotes"?

(Perhaps there is a better way to set up worktrees in general, but I understand that gets on the hairy edge of the "specific programming solution" scope of stack overflow.)

Comment: "*I could make it a regular clone, but then it has to have a branch checked out and then that branch cannot be checked out by any other worktree, so I'd have to make a dummy branch (e.g. wt_dummy) that could confuse people*" Why don't you create an empty commit and checkout it (as detached HEAD) in your non-bare repository?

Comment: A reasonable idea. You can even do `git clone --no-checkout --branch v1.0 <remote> reponame.wt` to give you a repo that is not checked out but has a HEAD pointing at the `v1.0` tag.

Answer (score 8):

You can configure a bare repository to have remote tracking branches with:

```
git config --local --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

Run `git fetch` and you should see them with `git branch -a`.

I don't believe it's possible to *not* have `master` (or another branch) checked out in the repository, but with a bare repository it's safe to create a linked worktree for it anyway, e.g.:

```
git worktree add --force <path> master
```

Even though `master` is checked out in the bare repository, there's no main worktree for it if the repository is bare, so you don't end up with two worktrees that would get out of sync.

Comment: Adding the refpsec using the git config command by @msleigh works a charm.  I'd also recommend that when cloning bare repo, use the  '--single-branch' option.   The result looks pretty much like a non-bare repository clone in terms of the remote branches.