# Git - reset local changes

Tags: git, github

I have done some local changes in code stored in Git repo. I don't need these changes anymore, so I would like to discard them and get a clean copy from github.

When I did a Git pull it gave me a merge conflict error.

So, I did

```
git reset --hard
```

but that did not help. I also tried

```
git stash
```

but still when I try pull from github, it does not allow me to do so.

Can someone please suggest what would be the best approach to get the latest code from github. Should I just delete the local files and then do a git pull?

Comment: It would be great if you post what errors are you getting. What exactly is "merge conflict error" and what github "does not allow you to do".

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

`git reset --hard {remote_name_here}/{branch_name_here}`

Comment: After doing git reset --hard master, when I did a git pull, it still complained about conflicts and asked me to merge

Comment: That's why I specified using the remote; if you add the remote to the command (probably `origin`) it will use the version pulled from that remote.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git checkout -f
```

For a great discussion of the differences between git reset and git checkout, see:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified#_git_reset

Comment: I did a git checkout -f and then did  git pull but it still complained of Conflicts. I would like my local copy to be overwritten with whatever is there in the remote repo. Don't want to do merging.

Comment: The command I recommended won't get rid of your local changes.  To do that you can wipe out the entire git directory and clone it again.   Alternatively look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head

Comment: It deleted all my files (that were not in project), it is not that I've expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the latest code pushed on remote, you can do that.

```
rm -rf ./gitProject

git clone yourRemoteRepo
```

Comment: I am skeptical about doing a delete of the local project, unless there is no better way. Doing a delete means those files which are not part of repo (and mentioned in .gitignore) will also go away.  All I want is my local copy to be overwritten with whatever is there in the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave out all your local changes and get only those from github you can just delete your `.git` folder and reinitialize it, like that :

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git remote add origin http://yourGithubUrl.com
git pull
```

Comment: Wanted to understand why this has been downvoted? Are there any potential challenges that I could run into if I do this?

Comment: Well, i can't see the point either.
What you will have with this, is a fresh copy of your project.
If you have any doubt, you can duplicate your project folder and test in the new one without any fear