# git reset --hard HEAD not work + pull -s recursive -X theirs still errors

Tags: git

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard HEAD
Checking out files: 100% (1806/1806), done.
HEAD is now at 2f557c9 Upload changes from public server
$ git pull -s recursive -X theirs
```

give

```
Auto-merging web/media/images/page-slider/salafitness1.jpg
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

there are many conflicts - how to force restore repository version?

```
git rebase master
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

give :
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git clean -f
```

work fine

Comment: Would you discard all local changes and just reset to the orgin HEAD? Maybe try a rebase before resetting to HEAD?...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head

Comment: You posted commands, that don't do what you want. Please, tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)